# Reading a UTF8 CSV file with Python

Tags: python, utf-8, csv, character-encoding

I am trying to read a CSV file with accented characters with Python (only French and/or Spanish characters). Based on the Python 2.5 documentation for the csvreader (http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html), I came up with the following code to read the CSV file since the csvreader supports only ASCII.

```
def unicode_csv_reader(unicode_csv_data, dialect=csv.excel, **kwargs):
    # csv.py doesn't do Unicode; encode temporarily as UTF-8:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(utf_8_encoder(unicode_csv_data),
                            dialect=dialect, **kwargs)
    for row in csv_reader:
        # decode UTF-8 back to Unicode, cell by cell:
        yield [unicode(cell, 'utf-8') for cell in row]

def utf_8_encoder(unicode_csv_data):
    for line in unicode_csv_data:
        yield line.encode('utf-8')

filename = 'output.csv'
reader = unicode_csv_reader(open(filename))
try:
    products = []
    for field1, field2, field3 in reader:
        ...
```

Below is an extract of the CSV file I am trying to read:

```
0665000FS10120684,SD1200IS,Appareil photo numérique PowerShot de 10 Mpx de Canon avec trépied (SD1200IS) - Bleu
0665000FS10120689,SD1200IS,Appareil photo numérique PowerShot de 10 Mpx de Canon avec trépied (SD1200IS) - Gris
0665000FS10120687,SD1200IS,Appareil photo numérique PowerShot de 10 Mpx de Canon avec trépied (SD1200IS) - Vert
...
```

Even though I try to encode/decode to UTF-8, I am still getting the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ".\Test.py", line 53, in <module>
    for field1, field2, field3 in reader:
  File ".\Test.py", line 40, in unicode_csv_reader
    for row in csv_reader:
  File ".\Test.py", line 46, in utf_8_encoder
    yield line.encode('utf-8', 'ignore')
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 68: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Martin, if you're around, would you consider switching the accepted answer from Martelli's Python 2 only answer.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

The `.encode` method gets applied to a Unicode string to make a byte-string; but you're calling it on a byte-string instead... the wrong way 'round!  Look at the `codecs` module in the standard library and `codecs.open` in particular for better general solutions for reading UTF-8 encoded text files. However, for the `csv` module in particular, you need to pass in utf-8 data, and that's what you're already getting, so your code can be much simpler:

```
import csv

def unicode_csv_reader(utf8_data, dialect=csv.excel, **kwargs):
    csv_reader = csv.reader(utf8_data, dialect=dialect, **kwargs)
    for row in csv_reader:
        yield [unicode(cell, 'utf-8') for cell in row]

filename = 'da.csv'
reader = unicode_csv_reader(open(filename))
for field1, field2, field3 in reader:
  print field1, field2, field3
```

PS: if it turns out that your input data is NOT in utf-8, but e.g. in ISO-8859-1, then you do need a "transcoding" (if you're keen on using utf-8 at the `csv` module level), of the form `line.decode('whateverweirdcodec').encode('utf-8')` -- but probably you can just use the name of your existing encoding in the `yield` line in my code above, instead of `'utf-8'`, as `csv` is actually going to be just fine with ISO-8859-* encoded bytestrings.

Comment: Does this mean the example in the python docs (where OP copy & pasted from) is wrong?   What is the point of the extra encoding step it does if it breaks when you give it a unicode csv?

Comment: **[Please see this answer for Python 3](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14786752/918959)**

Answer (score 111):

#### Python 2.X

There is a [unicode-csv](https://github.com/jdunck/python-unicodecsv) library which should solve your problems, with added benefit of not naving to write any new csv-related code.

Here is a example from their readme:

```
>>> import unicodecsv
>>> from cStringIO import StringIO
>>> f = StringIO()
>>> w = unicodecsv.writer(f, encoding='utf-8')
>>> w.writerow((u'é', u'ñ'))
>>> f.seek(0)
>>> r = unicodecsv.reader(f, encoding='utf-8')
>>> row = r.next()
>>> print row[0], row[1]
é ñ
```

#### Python 3.X

In python 3 this is supported out of the box by the build-in `csv` module. See this example:

```
import csv
with open('some.csv', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

Comment: `encoding='utf-8-sig'` helps if your CSV file has a [BOM prefix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark#Byte_order_marks_by_encoding) U+FEFF. Opening the file with that encoding will automatically strip the BOM. Otherwise it confuses `csv` into thinking the first field name starts with the BOM character and it fails to strip the quotes, and so reader.fieldnames[0] can be `'\ufeff"Date"'` instead of `'Date'`.

Answer (score 28):

If you want to read a CSV File with encoding utf-8, a minimalistic approach that I recommend you is to use something like this:

```
with open(file_name, encoding="utf8") as csv_file:
```

With that statement, you can use later a CSV reader to work with.

Comment: Is it possible that this is Python 3 only? It fails for me, in Python 2. It doesn't accept the `encoding` in `open`

Comment: @Zvika yes, in python 3 this solution works: `open('file.csv', 'r', encoding="ISO8859")`

Comment: I would also add open(file_name, "rt", encoding='utf-8'), that is, open file in "read text" mode

Comment: @JimmyLeeJones 'r' and 'rt' are the same since by default `open` use "read text" mode

Answer (score 6):

I suggest using the following code when you want to open the file.

```
open('/content/sasan.csv' , 'r', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore' )
```

Answer (score 3):

Also checkout the answer in this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/9347871/1338557

It suggests use of library called ucsv.py. Short and simple replacement for CSV written to address the encoding problem(utf-8) for Python 2.7. Also provides support for csv.DictReader

**Edit**: Adding sample code that I used:

```
import ucsv as csv

#Read CSV file containing the right tags to produce
fileObj = open('awol_title_strings.csv', 'rb')
dictReader = csv.DictReader(fileObj, fieldnames = ['titles', 'tags'], delimiter = ',', quotechar = '"')
#Build a dictionary from the CSV file-> {<string>:<tags to produce>}
titleStringsDict = dict()
for row in dictReader:
    titleStringsDict.update({unicode(row['titles']):unicode(row['tags'])})
```

Comment: you should put some details of that link in your answer, just in case the link goes broken\

Comment: #Downvoter- Not sure why you thought its of no use. The ucsv library worked just fine for me. Helped resolve the unicde error that I had been struggling with since 2 days. If you were looking for some sample code, here it goes in the edit
@Yaje- I have given some details; also the sample code. And corrected the link as well, that was earlier pointing to some other post.

Comment: Any particular reason you are opening a text file as a binary? 'rb' is for opening binary files.

Answer (score 2):

Using `codecs.open` as Alex Martelli suggested proved to be useful to me.

```
import codecs

delimiter = ';'
reader = codecs.open("your_filename.csv", 'r', encoding='utf-8')
for line in reader:
    row = line.split(delimiter)
    # do something with your row ...
```

Comment: It wouldn't work with all CSV, following is a valid csv row: "Foo Bar; Baz"; 231; 313; ";;;"; 1;

Comment: You import the `csv` module but do not use it.

Answer (score 1):

The link to the help page is the same for python 2.6 and as far as I know there was no change in the csv module since 2.5 (besides bug fixes).
Here is the code that just works without any encoding/decoding (file da.csv contains the same data as the variable *data*). I assume that your file should be read correctly without any conversions.

**test.py:**

```
## -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
# NOTE: this first line is important for the version b) read from a string(unicode) variable
#

import csv

data = \
"""0665000FS10120684,SD1200IS,Appareil photo numérique PowerShot de 10 Mpx de Canon avec trépied (SD1200IS) - Bleu
0665000FS10120689,SD1200IS,Appareil photo numérique PowerShot de 10 Mpx de Canon avec trépied (SD1200IS) - Gris
0665000FS10120687,SD1200IS,Appareil photo numérique PowerShot de 10 Mpx de Canon avec trépied (SD1200IS) - Vert"""

# a) read from a file
print 'reading from a file:'
for (f1, f2, f3) in csv.reader(open('da.csv'), dialect=csv.excel):
    print (f1, f2, f3)

# b) read from a string(unicode) variable
print 'reading from a list of strings:'
reader = csv.reader(data.split('\n'), dialect=csv.excel)
for (f1, f2, f3) in reader:
    print (f1, f2, f3)
```

**da.csv:**

```
0665000FS10120684,SD1200IS,Appareil photo numérique PowerShot de 10 Mpx de Canon avec trépied (SD1200IS) - Bleu
0665000FS10120689,SD1200IS,Appareil photo numérique PowerShot de 10 Mpx de Canon avec trépied (SD1200IS) - Gris
0665000FS10120687,SD1200IS,Appareil photo numérique PowerShot de 10 Mpx de Canon avec trépied (SD1200IS) - Vert
```

Comment: I wonder which version of python would this work in? I get errors with both 2.7 and 3.5. "ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)"

Comment: @eis: I can imagine that on your system comma is not a default delimiter. Try to add `delimiter=','` instead of `dialect=csv.excel`.

Answer (score 1):

Worth noting that if nothing worked for you, you may have forgotten to escape your path.
For example, this code:

```
f = open("C:\Some\Path\To\file.csv")
```

Would result in an error:

> SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes
>   in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

To fix, simply do:

```
f = open("C:\\Some\\Path\\To\\file.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [`Latin-1` unicode table](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0080.pdf), I see the character code `00E9` "*LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH ACUTE*". This is the accented character in your sample data. A simple test in `Python` shows that `UTF-8` encoding for this character is different from the unicode (almost `UTF-16`) encoding.

```
>>> u'\u00e9'
u'\xe9'
>>> u'\u00e9'.encode('utf-8')
'\xc3\xa9'
>>>
```

I suggest you try to `encode("UTF-8")` the unicode data before calling the special `unicode_csv_reader()`.
Simply reading the data from a file might hide the encoding, so check the actual character values.

Answer (score -1):

Had the same problem on another server, but realized that locales are messed.

```sh
export LC_ALL="en_US.UTF-8"
```

fixed the problem