# Python CSV error: line contains NULL byte

Tags: python, csv

I'm working with some CSV files, with the following code:

```
reader = csv.reader(open(filepath, "rU"))
try:
    for row in reader:
        print 'Row read successfully!', row
except csv.Error, e:
    sys.exit('file %s, line %d: %s' % (filename, reader.line_num, e))
```

And one file is throwing this error:

```
file my.csv, line 1: line contains NULL byte
```

What can I do? Google seems to suggest that it may be an Excel file that's been saved as a .csv improperly. Is there any way I can get round this problem in Python?

== UPDATE ==

Following @JohnMachin's comment below, I tried adding these lines to my script:

```
print repr(open(filepath, 'rb').read(200)) # dump 1st 200 bytes of file
data = open(filepath, 'rb').read()
print data.find('\x00')
print data.count('\x00')
```

And this is the output I got:

```
'\xd0\xcf\x11\xe0\xa1\xb1\x1a\xe1\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\ .... <snip>
8
13834
```

So the file does indeed contain NUL bytes.

Comment: What does `od -c` say the first line looks like?

Comment: what query should I run, something like cat my.csv | od -c | more ? with that I get: 0000000    D   e   p   a   r   t   m   e   n   t       F   a   m   i   l

Comment: How is the CSV generated ? From excel, you may be able to try a dialect.  Otherwise look at say: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753022/python-finding-unicode-ascii-problems

Comment: Thanks. It's not my CSV, and unfortunately I don't have the power to change it. I think it's been created as Excel and saved as CSV (boo). A dialect sounds like a good idea - I'll try that!

Comment: If it's actually been saved as CSV, it should work. One thing I sometimes find is TSV (tab separated) files masquerading as CSV, so you could try setting a delimiter of '\t'.
If it's been saved as an Excel file, and the extension changed to CSV, no dialect is going to work. I think your only option in that case would be to use Excel to save copies as proper CSV.

Comment: And I spoke too soon: there is even a Python package to read xls files, called xlrd. No idea how well it works, though. http://www.python-excel.org/

Comment: @AP257: Ignacio meant the first line in the file, not just the first line (only 16 bytes worth) of od's output. You need to dump more; see my answer.

Comment: Preprocessing the file from the terminal to strip NUL bytes worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2398400

Comment: So you know, one thing that helped eliminate the CSV formatting was opening it in NotePad ++ and verifying the encoding. My issue was an encoding one. I hope this adds to the resolution for any other person looking into this error.

Answer (score 121):

As @S.Lott says, you should be opening your files in 'rb' mode, not 'rU' mode. However that may NOT be causing your current problem. As far as I know, using 'rU' mode would mess you up if there are embedded `\r` in the data, but not cause any other dramas. I also note that you have several files (all opened with 'rU' ??) but only one causing a problem.

If the csv module says that you have a "NULL" (silly message, should be "NUL") byte in your file, then you need to check out what is in your file. I would suggest that you do this even if using 'rb' makes the problem go away.

`repr()` is (or wants to be) your debugging friend. It will show unambiguously what you've got, in a platform independant fashion (which is helpful to helpers who are unaware what `od` is or does). Do this:

```
print repr(open('my.csv', 'rb').read(200)) # dump 1st 200 bytes of file
```

and carefully copy/paste (don't retype) the result into an edit of your question (not into a comment).

Also note that if the file is really dodgy e.g. no \r or \n within reasonable distance from the start of the file, the line number reported by `reader.line_num` will be (unhelpfully) 1. Find where the first `\x00` is (if any) by doing

```
data = open('my.csv', 'rb').read()
print data.find('\x00')
```

and make sure that you dump at least that many bytes with repr or od.

What does `data.count('\x00')` tell you? If there are many, you may want to do something like

```
for i, c in enumerate(data):
    if c == '\x00':
        print i, repr(data[i-30:i]) + ' *NUL* ' + repr(data[i+1:i+31])
```

so that you can see the NUL bytes in context.

If you can see `\x00` in the output (or `\0` in your `od -c` output), then you definitely have NUL byte(s) in the file, and you will need to do something like this:

```
fi = open('my.csv', 'rb')
data = fi.read()
fi.close()
fo = open('mynew.csv', 'wb')
fo.write(data.replace('\x00', ''))
fo.close()
```

By the way, have you looked at the file (including the last few lines) with a text editor? Does it actually look like a reasonable CSV file like the other (no "NULL byte" exception) files?

Comment: Thank you so much for this very detailed help. There are lots of \x00 characters in the file (see edit to question) - it's odd, because in a text editor it looks like a perfectly reasonable CSV file.

Comment: @AP257: `'\xd0\xcf\x11\xe0\xa1\xb1\x1a\xe1` is the "signature" denoting an OLE2 Compound Document file -- e.g. an **Excel 97-2003 .XLS file**. I find "in a text editor it looks like a perfectly reasonable CSV file" to be **utterly unbelievable**. You must have been looking at a different file, a valid CSV file, in another folder or on another machine or at some other time. Note that your `od` output wasn't from an XLS file.

Comment: Works, but should be possible and nice on-the-fly with a file-like object that filters the CSV and can be passed to `csv.reader` directly.

Comment: I think `od` is a typo for `os` in this answer.

Comment: @lin_bug od is a unix utility program ... name is short for "octal dump"

Comment: Shouldn't `fo.write(data.replace('\x00', ''))` be `fo.write(data.replace(b'\x00', b''))`? Python 3.6 here...

Comment: (+1) for those interested in following the answer here -- note that depending on the size of your file, that `for i, c in enumerate(data)` call could take a very long time...

Answer (score 30):

```
data_initial = open("staff.csv", "rb")
data = csv.reader((line.replace('\0','') for line in data_initial), delimiter=",")
```

This works for me.

Comment: Solved for my case, the null were the '\0' values. Thanks.

Answer (score 22):

Reading it as UTF-16 was also my problem.

Here's my code that ended up working:

```
f=codecs.open(location,"rb","utf-16")
csvread=csv.reader(f,delimiter='\t')
csvread.next()
for row in csvread:
    print row
```

Where location is the directory of your csv file.

Answer (score 17):

You could just inline a generator to filter out the null values if you want to pretend they don't exist.  Of course this is assuming the null bytes are not really part of the encoding and really are some kind of erroneous artifact or bug.

```
with open(filepath, "rb") as f:
    reader = csv.reader( (line.replace('\0','') for line in f) )

    try:
        for row in reader:
            print 'Row read successfully!', row
    except csv.Error, e:
        sys.exit('file %s, line %d: %s' % (filename, reader.line_num, e))
```

Answer (score 14):

I bumped into this problem as well.  Using the Python `csv` module, I was trying to read an XLS file created in MS Excel and running into the `NULL byte` error you were getting.  I looked around and found the [xlrd](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd) Python module for reading and formatting data from MS Excel spreadsheet files.  With the `xlrd` module, I am not only able to read the file properly, but I can also access many different parts of the file in a way I couldn't before.

I thought it might help you.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that module. Interestingly enough, I went to download it and noticed the author was none other than @John_Machin who is also the top comment on this question.

Answer (score 11):

Converting the encoding of the source file from UTF-16 to UTF-8 solve my problem.

[How to convert a file to utf-8 in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191359/how-to-convert-a-file-to-utf-8-in-python)

```
import codecs
BLOCKSIZE = 1048576 # or some other, desired size in bytes
with codecs.open(sourceFileName, "r", "utf-16") as sourceFile:
    with codecs.open(targetFileName, "w", "utf-8") as targetFile:
        while True:
            contents = sourceFile.read(BLOCKSIZE)
            if not contents:
                break
            targetFile.write(contents)
```

Answer (score 2):

Why are you doing this?

```
 reader = csv.reader(open(filepath, "rU"))
```

The docs are pretty clear that you must do this:

```
with open(filepath, "rb") as src:
    reader= csv.reader( src )
```

The mode must be "rb" to read.

http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.reader

> If csvfile is a file object, it must be opened with the ‘b’ flag on platforms where that makes a difference.

Comment: @AP257: "Doesn't help"?  Means what?  Any specific error messages?

Comment: @S.Lott: Means he gets the same answer as before. The reality is that he is dealing with a chameleon or shapeshifter file ... when he dumps it with `od` or looks at it in a text editor, it looks like a perfectly normal CSV file. However when he dumps the first few bytes with Python repr(), it makes like an Excel .XLS file (that's been renamed to have a CSV extension).

Comment: @John Machin: "an Excel .XLS file (that's been renamed to have a CSV extension"  Makes sense that it cannot be processed at all.

Comment: @S.Lott: With that content, it makes sense that the csv module can't process it; however the xlrd module can process it. Sensibly, neither module infers anything from the name of the input file, if indeed the input is a file with a name.

Comment: @John Machin: "neither module infers anything from the name of the input file".  True.  My application framework depends on that fact.  We don't trust the filename to mean anything, since people make mistakes ("lie").  So we have to check a bunch of alternatives until one clicks.

Comment: I just had an interesting experience with a "csv" file which looked perfectly normal in Notepad++ yet was giving the null byte error when reading it using CSV module in Python 2.7.9. Turns out Notepad++ is detecting a unicode encoding and generously/helpfully hiding this from me, whereas CSV expects ASCII. Doesn't seem to be a way to make NP++ open in 'raw', but at least it lets me convert to ANSI and then I could read it using CSV. Word of warning, really, not to assume that apparent OKness in NP++ is proof of no non-ASCII data.

Comment: Python 2 required mode `"rb"`. Python 3 instead requires mode `"r"`.

Answer (score 2):

appparently it's a XLS file and not a CSV file as http://www.garykessler.net/library/file_sigs.html confirm

Comment: Not necessarily, but yes, this could be a cause. I did get this error when I tried parsing a CSV file that was saved by Excel from an XLSX file.

Comment: With this magic number it's the cause XLSX have different magic number

Answer (score 2):

Instead of csv reader I use read file and split function for string:

```
lines = open(input_file,'rb') 

for line_all in lines:

    line=line_all.replace('\x00', '').split(";")
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error. Saved the file in UTF-8 and it worked.

Comment: You may have got the same error message, but the cause would have been different -- you probably saved it originally as UTF-16 (what Notepad calls "Unicode").

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me when I created a CSV file with OpenOffice Calc. It didn't happen when I created the CSV file in my text editor, even if I later edited it with Calc.

I solved my problem by copy-pasting in my text editor the data  from my Calc-created file to a new editor-created file.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem opening a CSV produced from a webservice which inserted NULL bytes in empty headers. I did the following to clean the file:

```
with codecs.open ('my.csv', 'rb', 'utf-8') as myfile:
    data = myfile.read()
    # clean file first if dirty
    if data.count( '\x00' ):
        print 'Cleaning...'
        with codecs.open('my.csv.tmp', 'w', 'utf-8') as of:
            for line in data:
                of.write(line.replace('\x00', ''))

        shutil.move( 'my.csv.tmp', 'my.csv' )

with codecs.open ('my.csv', 'rb', 'utf-8') as myfile:
    myreader = csv.reader(myfile, delimiter=',')
    # Continue with your business logic here...
```

Disclaimer:
Be aware that this overwrites your original data. Make sure you have a backup copy of it. You have been warned!

Answer (score 1):

I opened and saved the original csv file as a `.csv` file through Excel's "Save As" and the NULL byte disappeared.

I think the original encoding for the file I received was double byte unicode (it had a null character every other character) so saving it through excel fixed the encoding.

Answer (score 1):

Remove or replace `null bytes`:

```
with open('your_file.csv', 'rb') as file:
    data = file.read().replace(b'\x00', b'')
with open('your_file.csv', 'wb') as file:
    file.write(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

For all those 'rU' filemode haters: I just tried opening a CSV file from a Windows machine on a Mac with the 'rb' filemode and I got this error from the csv module:

```
Error: new-line character seen in unquoted field - do you need to 
open the file in universal-newline mode?
```

Opening the file in 'rU' mode works fine. I love universal-newline mode -- it saves me so much hassle.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this when using scrapy and fetching a zipped csvfile without having a correct middleware to unzip the response body before handing it to the csvreader. Hence the file was not really a csv file and threw the `line contains NULL byte` error accordingly.

Comment: hey mate,
can you please explain to me, how did you configure the right csv.middleware? I got the same exact error like you described :(

Comment: @y.y Certainly, this is what I wrote 
https://gist.github.com/Gesias/b9ae4593ae7ba7584bf6bcf295f18ffd

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using gzip.open?

```
with gzip.open('my.csv', 'rb') as data_file:
```

I was trying to open a file that had been compressed but had the extension '.csv' instead of 'csv.gz'. This error kept showing up until I used gzip.open

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is taking a more manual approach of blacklisting certain characters. In the data I was working with, an ASCII control character indicated that the row was corrupted. This script looks for any "bad" characters, and if found, skips the row entirely. It assumes that the CSV header in the first row isn't corrupted though. With this approach, the corrupted data is intercepted before it reaches `csv.DictReader` which then throws a null byte error.

```py
import io, csv

# Problematic ASCII control characters.
ascii_control_characters = list(range(0, 31))
ascii_control_characters.append(127) # Delete.
ascii_control_characters.remove(10) # Line feed.
ascii_control_characters.remove(13) # Carriage return.

with open('/foo/bar/baz.csv', 'r') as data_file:
    header = ''

    for index, line in enumerate(data_file):
        # Search line for problematic ASCII characters.
        bad_character_found = False

        for character in line:
            if ord(character) in ascii_control_characters:
                bad_character_found = True
                break

        # If a bad character is found, skip the line altogether.
        if bad_character_found:
            print(
                'Corrupted data found on line: ' + \
                 str(index + 1) + \
                 '. Skipping...'
            )

            continue

        if index == 0:
            header += line
            continue

        csv_data = header + line

        reader = csv.DictReader(io.StringIO(csv_data))

        for row in reader:
            # Process each CSV row here.
            pass
```

Answer (score -2):

One case is that - If the CSV file contains empty rows this error may show up. Check for row is necessary before we proceed to write or read.

```
for row in csvreader:
        if (row):       
            do something
```

I solved my issue by adding this check in the code.