# reading a comma separtated text file containing special characters in python

Tags: python, csv

```
import csv,sys

phile="E:/Users/san/Documents/phonebook.txt"
ph=open(phile,"rt")
try:
    lines= csv.reader(ph)


    for each in lines:
        print each,
except Exception as er:
       print er
finally: ph.close()
```

getting error saying that " line contains NULL byte" !!

Comment: If you post a sample line from the .txt file that is causing the problem, that would be helpful.

Comment: wish i could but this is all the error i get and its a phonebook exported from my phone in text format..

Comment: i guess it was the first line of text file , i saved it as ansi and it printed well except the first line conatains this text "ï»¿" which i guess is thecause but i do not see it when i open the file in notepad

Comment: Take a look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166070/python-csv-error-line-contains-null-byte) , it sounds like the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My other guess is that the `open(phile, "rt")` should just be `open(phile, "rb")`.

You can also debug which line number this happens on (or one before) by doing this:

```
for line_number, each in enumerate(lines):
    print line_number, each
```