# Reading tab delimited unicode data into R via read.table

Tags: r, unicode, read.table

I have several files exported out of a Sql-Server database as tab-delimited unicode text (numeric data & foreign names).

How do I load these files into R?

There is a special character in the first position of each file. I assume that's the BOM.

Without any options (beyond `header` and `sep`), `read.table` puts all the data into one column, even with the proper `\t` separator specification.

Opening a connection and skipping the first three bytes leads to `empty beginning of file`.

I've tried all available `fileEncoding` values: I get either `line 1 didn't have 29 elements` or `more columns than column names`.

I'm really stumped on this one. Ideally I'd like to have everything handled within R, but any awk/powershell advice to fix these files is welcome. Is it just a BOM issue? One thing I can't do is control the export from Sql-Server (I don't own the SSIS package). Thanks.

EDIT

For those interested in getting to data columns in a csv exported by SqlServer with the unicode option on: SqlServer starts its csv exports with a NUL character. This link discusses how to actually 'see' those special characters:

[Python CSV error: line contains NULL byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166070/python-csv-error-line-contains-null-byte)

EDIT

This is what I've put together to get ASCII and move along. It's not the answer to my question though.

```
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import unicodedata
import codecs

mypath = "C:\\Users\\Collapsed\\data"

filesOnly = [ f for f in listdir(mypath) if isfile(join(mypath,f)) ]

for f in filesOnly:
     print f
     fln = mypath + "\\" + f
     fl_in  = codecs.open( fln , 'Ur', 'utf-16')
     fl_out = open( mypath + "\\" + 'ascii_' + f , 'w' ) 
     for line in fl_in:
         fl_out.write( unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', line ).encode('ascii','ignore') )
     fl_in.close()
     fl_out.close()
```

Comment: You skip the first line when reading e.g. `read.table(file,skip=1)`, if it did not work post an example of your file

Comment: I get `empty beginning of file` without `fileEncoding`, and `more columns than column names` using `fileEncoding`. I tried with `header=T` and 'header=F'. The name fields are persons' names: can't post.

Comment: I tried [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068650/using-awk-to-remove-the-byte-order-mark) but `read.table` still collapses all columns into one. If it can help, Excel reads the data without any problem (with and without the `awk` BOM cleanup above).

Comment: And I also have `comment.char=""`,`quote=""`.

Comment: Can't insert code here.