# CSV reader: line contains NULL byte

Tags: python

(This question is related to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166070/python-csv-error-line-contains-null-byte))

I am reading parsing csv content, which has been previously loaded into memory:

```
def ReadTxtIntoColumns(txt, columns):
    rows = []
    print txt
    print txt.find('\x00')
    print txt.count('\x00')
    f = StringIO(txt)
    try:
        reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
        for row in reader:
            # Merge all extra columns
            if len(row) >= columns:
                rest = ' '.join(row[columns-1:])
                del row[columns-1:]
                row.append(rest)
            # And now set missing columns to None
            for i in range (len (row), columns):
                row.append(None)
            rows.append(row)
    except csv.Error, e:
        log.error('ReadTxtIntoColumns > Problems reading csv from string > line %d: %s', reader.line_num, e)
    finally:
        f.close()
    return rows
```

The input data has been hand-written by me (a simple textfile, space separated). There is no '\x00' at all in my input data, but csv complains about it:

```
ReadTxtIntoColumns > Problems reading csv from string > line 1: line contains NULL byte
```

What does the error message mean then?

## EDIT

This is my simplified input data, which I have verified is still causing the same problem:

```
#COMMAND                      USER        DIRECTORY                        SAFE   COMMAND
uname                         -            -                               FALSE  uname -a
sleep                         -            -                               FALSE  sleep 100
```

Comment: You don't need to wrap the input in a `StringIO` object; just pass in any iterable; `text.splitlines(True)` will do fine, for example.

Comment: Can you give us a minimal sample `text` value that reproduces the problem?

Comment: wouldn't `numpy.loadtxt` work for your case?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: Added input data. The funny thing, I am having this problem in one system, but not in another system. csv library is the same in both. One is python 2.7.3 (ok), the other 2.7.2 (error)

Comment: @gonvaled: Is there any Unicode involved?

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: there shouldn't be. The input file is just simple text without special characters written in emacs, so I assume is just simple ascii encoding.

Comment: @gonvaled: I am talking about the type in Python, `type(txt)` should be `str`, not `unicode`, as `StringIO` won't handle that correctly.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: let me check again. I am processing the input file with `pystache`, and I have extended my pystache wrapper lately to handle unicode. If I verify the type of `txt` it is indeed unicode, so that could be the problem. The question still remains why that does not cause problem with python 2.7.3. And more important for me: how to parse the unicode csv with the csv module?

Comment: @gonvaled: Neither the `csv` module nor the `StringIO` object support `unicode` data. See the warning on top of  http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html.

Comment: Oh, now I see your comment. So `StringIO` is the problem? I'll check that. How to pass an iterable to the csv reader? Why is python 2.7.3 StrinIO happy about it?

Comment: gonvaled: I think @Martijn was suggesting that for data this simple you don't really need to use the `csv` module at all. In that spirit I'd suggest using `for row in txt.splitlines():` instead of `for row in reader:`.

Comment: @martineau: No; I wasn't necessarily suggesting that; you can pass the result of `txt.splitlines(True)` to the `csv.reader()` object and it'll work, provided `txt` is a byte string, not `unicode`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`csv` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) contains the following warning:

> This version of the csv module doesn’t support Unicode input. Also, there are currently some issues regarding ASCII NUL characters. Accordingly, all input should be UTF-8 or printable ASCII to be safe; see the examples in section Examples.

The `StringIO.StringIO` object supports unicode, but if you are using the `cStringIO` module, then `cStringIO.StringIO` doesn't, and can lead to more problems.

If your data is ASCII only, simply encode `txt` first:

```
txt = txt.encode()
```

There could have been some fixes added to 2.7.3 that make the problem less visible.

Answer (score 1):

csv module has problems reading data from Unicode encoded files.  Your code worked when I pasted it into the python interpreter and called it with a manually entered text string, so it should work if you try saving the file in ANSI/ASCII format, or converting it to ASCII when loading it into memory.