# Python continue for loop after exception

Tags: python, for-loop, try-catch

I'm trying to create a new version of a file that excludes NULL bytes.  I'm using the code below to attempt this however it's still breaking on the NULL byte.  How should I structure the `for` statement and `try-catch` block to keep going after the exception?

```
import csv

input_file = "/data/train.txt"
outFileName = "/data/train_no_null.txt"
############################

i_f = open( input_file, 'r' )
reader = csv.reader( i_f , delimiter = '|' )

outFile = open(outFileName, 'wb') 
mywriter = csv.writer(outFile, delimiter = '|')

i_f.seek( 0 )
i = 1

for line in reader:
    try:
        i += 1
        mywriter.writerow(line)

    except csv.Error:
        print('csv choked on line %s' % (i + 1))
        pass
```

EDIT:

Here's the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "20150310_rewrite_csv_wo_NULL.py", line 26, in <module>
    for line in reader:
_csv.Error: line contains NULL byte
```

UPDATE:

I'm using this code:

```
i_f = open( input_file, 'r' )
reader = csv.reader( i_f , delimiter = '|' )
# reader.next()

outFile = open(outFileName, 'wb') 
mywriter = csv.writer(outFile, delimiter = '|')

i_f.seek( 0 )
i = 1


for idx, line in enumerate(reader):
    try:
        mywriter.writerow(line)
    except:
        print('csv choked on line %s' % idx)
```

and now get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "20150310_rewrite_csv_wo_NULL.py", line 26, in <module>
    for idx, line in enumerate(reader):
_csv.Error: line contains NULL byte
```

Comment: What error do you get? If not an `csv.Error`, then you simply need more except clause(s) to handle them.

Comment: @mdurant: see edit above.

Comment: You can see the "_" character... so it's an exceptions defined in a module somewhere within csv.

Comment: @mdurant: does that mean I need to handle it differently?

Comment: Just wondering if you've seen this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166070/python-csv-error-line-contains-null-byte ?

Comment: @CaptainWhippet: I have, the one other caveat is that the file I'm working with is 20GB so I can't read into memory before rewriting.

Answer (score 0):

You can catch all errors with the following code...

```
for idx, line in enumerate(reader):
    try:
        mywriter.writerow(line)
    except:
        print('csv choked on line %s' % idx)
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception is being thrown from the reader, which is not being caught as it is outside of the try/catch.

But even if it was, the reader won't want to continue after its encounter with the NUL byte. But if the reader never saw it, along the lines of...

```
for idx, line in enumerate(csv.reader((line.replace('\0','') for line in open('myfile.csv')), delimiter='|')):
```

you might be OK.

Really though, you should find out where the NUL bytes are coming from as they might be symptomatic of a wider problem with your data.

Comment: the data is coming out of a redshift database and generally hanging out in S3.  Any idea if it's a function of that environment or it's in the data before going into redshift?

Comment: I'm not sure how you've ended up with those NUL bytes in the data then, getting them into Redshift would be difficult: _If your data includes a null terminator, also referred to as NUL (UTF-8 0000) or binary zero (0x000), COPY treats it as an end of record (EOR) and terminates the record._ [http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html]. And if you can't get them in there, I don't know how you got them back out!