# python3 csv with duplicate keys + python defaultdict

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a csv file which is having lot of serial numbers and material numbers for ex:  show below (I need only first 2columns i.e serial and chassis and rest is not required).

```
serial          chassis      type   date
ZX34215         Test         XX     YY
ZX34215         final-001    XX     YY
AB30000         Used         XX     YY
ZX34215         final-002    XX     YY
```

I have below snippet which gets all the serial and material numbers into a dictionary but here duplicate keys are eliminated and it captures latest serial key.

## Working code

```
import sys
import csv 
with open('file1.csv', mode='r') as infile:
        reader = csv.reader(infile)
        mydict1 = {rows[0]:rows[1] for rows in reader}
        print(mydict1)
```

I need to capture duplicate keys with respective values also but it failed. I used python defaultdict and looks like I missed something here.

## not working

```
from collections import defaultdict
with open('file1.csv',mode='r') as infile:
    data=defaultdict(dict)
    reader=csv.reader(infile)
    list_res = list(reader)
    for row in reader:
        result=data[row[0]].append(row[1])
        print(result)
```

Can some one correct me to capture duplicate keys into dictionary.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove specific characters from a string in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939361/remove-specific-characters-from-a-string-in-python)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass a list to your `defaultdict` not `dict` :

```
data=defaultdict(list)
```

Also you don't need to convert the `reader` object to list, for iterating over it, you also shouldn't assign the append snipped to a variable in each iteration:

```
data=defaultdict(list)
with open('file1.csv') as infile:
    reader=csv.reader(infile)
    for row in reader:
        try:      
            data[row[0]].append(row[1])
        except IndexError:
            pass
    print(data)
```

Comment: Hi I have many columns which i am igonring and need to consider only first 2 columns in csv (serial and chassis) so in this case for my actual csv file, I get below error:                for col1, col2 in reader:
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Comment: @VinodHC It's because of that your rows haven't same number of items. You can use a `try-except` expression to handle the error.

Comment: Hi I have some empty serial number rows in csv file and I get below error, How to ignore this and continue:                                                                        for row in reader:
_csv.Error: line contains NULL byte

Comment: @VinodHC http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166070/python-csv-error-line-contains-null-byte