# CSV Error: Line contains NULL byte

Tags: python, csv

I am trying to read a csv file. Here is my code:

```
import csv
openFile = open('example.csv')
fileRead = csv.reader(openFile)
fileRead = list(fileRead)
print fileRead[0]
```

I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/bob/PycharmProjects/Random/random.py", line 5, in <module>
    fileRead = list(fileRead)
_csv.Error: line contains NULL byte
```

Comment: `csv` package does not support binary data. Is this expected? or the file is corrupt.

Comment: Well, the error already tells you everything you need to know:  that file is an invalid csv file. Either change the file to not-contain null bytes, or use a different/your own parser to parse it.

Comment: Thanks Jean! Turns out it was corrupt.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python CSV error: line contains NULL byte](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166070/python-csv-error-line-contains-null-byte)