# Cant read arabic CSV file for sentiment analysis in arabic jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, sentiment-analysis

I have searched everywhere for a solution for this particular error and tried them all and none worked I have searched in this forum and worked out every answer and it did not work at all.

This is my code:

```
X_train, Y_train = read_csv('Data/train_emoji_ar.csv')
```

this is the error I keep getting

```
Error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-3f5fe77b4b07> in <module>
----> 1 X_train, Y_train = read_csv('Data/train_emoji_ar.csv')

~\emo_utils.py in read_csv(filename)
     38         csvReader = csv.reader(csvDataFile)
     39 
---> 40         for row in csvReader:
     41             phrase.append(row[0])
     42             emoji.append(row[1])

Error: line contains NULL byte
```

and when I open my CSV file that is saved in jupyter note book I see this error:

[image]

However, when it is in English it works fine and opens fine unlike when it is in arabic.

The part of my python code in my emo_utils.py which reads the csv:

```
def read_csv(filename):
    phrase = []
    emoji = []

    with open (filename) as csvDataFile:
        csvReader = csv.reader(csvDataFile)

        for row in csvReader:
            phrase.append(row[0])
            emoji.append(row[1])

    X = np.asanyarray(phrase)
    Y = np.asanyarray(emoji, dtype=int)

    return X, Y
```

so please help me why I keep getting this issue:

I tried using UTF encoding
newline
and many

None worked

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python CSV error: line contains NULL byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166070/python-csv-error-line-contains-null-byte)

Comment: The problem is that jupyter notebook is not reading the CSV file I am uploading

Comment: Is the error in this post not `Error: line contains NULL byte`? And is the error in [Python CSV error: line contains NULL byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166070/python-csv-error-line-contains-null-byte) not `error: line contains NULL byte`? I understand that this isn't a bespoke solution, but it appears to be the same root cause. Have you tried opening the file in binary mode, and if so: what happened?