# Unicode Decoding error with xlwt

Tags: python, xlwt

I'm trying to backport a script to Python 2.4 and an error that keeps coming up is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last)
    File "vuln-excel-processor.py", line 103, in ?
        values[row][col] = str(sheet.cell(row + 1, col).value).decode('utf-8')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2013' in position 44: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Here's the offending code block.

```
for row in range(sheet.nrows - 1):
    for col in range(sheet.ncols):
        values[row][col] = str(sheet.cell(row + 1, col).value).decode('utf-8')
```

I found this page discussing this error [Python - Finding unicode/ascii problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753022/python-finding-unicode-ascii-problems), which prompted me to put the call to str.decode() in the last line but that failed to resolve the problem.  Any ideas on the culprit here?  Much thanks for any assistance.