# UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe3

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-unicode, mime-mail

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe3

I am facing this issue while running a mailing script in py 2.7 for the line...

msg.attach(MIMEText(welcome_msg + htmlMessageContent + footer_msg, 'html'))

Comment: Don't assume that the string is utf-8 encoded. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21129020/how-to-fix-unicodedecodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-decode-byte

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - Finding unicode/ascii problems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2753022/python-finding-unicode-ascii-problems)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the elements of the string you are concatenating

```
welcome_msg + htmlMessageContent + footer_msg
```

is Unicode, and another of them isn't. When you concatenate the strings Python has convert them all to a common type (Unicode), much as it does when you add an integer to a float. But the default string conversion to Unicode is ascii, and if the string contains a non-ascii character it will fail.

Find out which string isn't Unicode. For this you can use `type()`. Wrap that string in a call to `unicode()` that explains how you want `'\xe3'` interpreted. 
For example, if `'\xe3'` should be interpreted as `'ã'`:

```
unicode(mystring, encoding='Latin-1')
```

Then your concatenation should work.

Comment: This obviously assumes the other stringtis Latin-1 which could be completely wrong. The real solution is to know what you have, and take it from there.

Comment: That was a guess, and a reasonable one. If OP doesn't want want '\xe3' interpreted as 'ã' then he will need to find the encoding he needs. But to provide a testable solution I had to put in a real encoding name. Answering a question at this level with `encoding='your encoding goes here'` is, in my opinion, not all that helpful. Your comment assumes that OP knows what an encoding is.

Comment: The problem is more that the OP posted a fundamentally incomplete question, but IMHO,  it bears pointing out that *blindly* applying a workaround without understanding it properly will just introduce new bugs.

Comment: i had to encode the first and last strings in order to get rid of the errot