# Does python 3.1.3 support unicode in csv module?

Tags: python, csv

I have been using python 2.6. While I was writing a python program to process the query result ( in csv format ) from sql server. I found it does not support unicode.

When I run the program with csv file, a error poped up saying:

```
    for row in csvReader:
Error: line contains NULL byte
```

After I save the csv file in ANSI/ASCII format with Ultraedit, the program is running okay.

I tried to include the encoding option, but it failed:

```
csvReader = csv.reader(open(fname, mode='rb', encoding='unicode'), delimiter=',')
TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

csvReader = csv.reader(open(fname, mode='rb', encoding='utf-8'), delimiter=',')
TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

I wonder if python 3 support this unicode reading. It can save me a lot of work.

Comment: Why don't you access the SQL directly from python?

Comment: Python 3.1.3's `open` *definitely* supports and `encoding=` argument, so either you're using a different version of Python, or you have accidentally overwritten the `open` function.

Comment: I said I am using python 2.6. So Python 3.1.3 won't have this problem?

Comment: Python 3 still have this problem. Apparently there are a NUL byte there messing up python, no matter it is python 3 or python 2.

Comment: Oh, sorry, it wasn't clear that you were using Python 2.6. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 7):

Python 3 definitely supports unicode. My guess is that you specified the wrong (or no?) encoding when you opened the CSV file for reading. See: http://docs.python.org/release/3.1.3/library/functions.html#open

And try something like:

```
reader = csv.reader(open("foo.csv", encoding="utf-8"))
```

**Edit**: If you are using Python 2.6, you can achieve the same result with:

```
import codecs
reader = csv.reader(codecs.open("foo.csv", encoding="utf-8"))
```

*HOWEVER* if you're getting null bytes, your file may be encoded using `"utf-16"`, so try that if the file can't be decoded using utf-8.

Comment: I tried to specified the encoding, but it return an error. Please check my edit.

Answer (score 2):

A similar question is already answered [Python CSV error: line contains NULL byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166070/python-csv-error-line-contains-null-byte)

Also, Try to open it in 'rb' mode instead of 'rU'