# python unicode csv export using pyramid

Tags: python, pyramid, export-to-csv

I'm trying to export mongodb that has non ascii characters into csv format.
Right now, I'm dabbling with pyramid and using pyramid.response.

```
from pyramid.response import Response
from mycart.Member import Member

@view_config(context="mycart:resources.Member", name='', request_method="POST", permission = 'admin')
def member_export( context, request):
     filename = 'member-'+time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")+".csv"
     download_path = os.getcwd() + '/MyCart/mycart/static/downloads/'+filename

     member = Members(request)

     my_list = [['First Name,Last Name']]

     record = member.get_all_member( )             
     for r in record:

         mystr = [ r['fname'],  r['lname']]

         my_list.append(mystr)

     with open(download_path, 'wb') as f:
         fileWriter = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',',quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
         for l in my_list:
             print(l)
             fileWriter.writerow(l)

     size = os.path.getsize(download_path)
     response = Response(content_type='application/force-download', content_disposition='attachment; filename=' + filename)
     response.app_iter = open(download_path , 'rb')
     response.content_length = size

     return response
```

In mongoDB, first name is showing `王`, when I'm using print, it too is showing `王`. However, when I used excel to open it up, it shows random stuff - ç¾…

However, when I tried to view it in shell

```
$ more member-20130227141550.csv
```

It managed to display the non ascii character correctly.

How should I rectify this problem?

Comment: May be you can try something mentioned in this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4182603/python-how-to-convert-a-string-to-utf-8)

Comment: Or you can use unicodecsv to do the job, [unicodecsv](https://github.com/jdunck/python-unicodecsv) since python's internal csv module doesn't support unicode.

Comment: Excel interprets CSV files according to the current language settings of the computer. It doesn't recognize UTF-8 and instead will happily mis-interpret the data as a different encoding. Solution: target your CSV encoding to whomever is going to use it.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not a Windows guy, so I am not sure whether the problem may be with your code or with excel just not handling non-ascii characters nicely.  But I have noticed that you are writing your file with python [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module, which is [notorious for headaches with unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846135/python-csv-library-with-unicode-utf-8-support-that-just-works).

Other users have reported success with using [`unicodecsv`](https://github.com/jdunck/python-unicodecsv) as a replacement for the csv module.  Perhaps you could try dropping in this module as a csv writer and see if your problem magically goes away.