# Python Pandas converting strings to NaN

Tags: python, excel, unicode, pandas, scipy

So I am using pandas to read in excel files and csv files. These files contain both strings and numbers not just numbers. Problem is all my strings get converted into NaN which I do not want at all. I do not know what the types of the columns will be ahead of time (it is actually my job to handle the system that figures this out) so I can't tell pandas what they will be (that must come later). I just want to read in each cell as a string for now.

here is my code

```
if csv: #check weather to read in excell file or csv
  frame = pandas.read_csv(io.StringIO(data))
else:
  frame = pandas.read_excel(io.StringIO(data))
tbl = []
print frame.dtypes
for (i, col) in enumerate(frame):
  tmp = [col]
  for (j, value) in enumerate(frame[col]):
    tmp.append(unicode(value))
  tbl.append(tmp)
```

I just need to be able to produce a column wise 2D list and I can do everything from there. I also need to be able to handle Unicode (data is already in Unicode).

How do I construct 'tbl' so that cells that should be strings do not come out as 'NaN'?

Comment: Is the problem occurring with CSV files or Excel files?  Add a sample file to the question so we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Did you read documentation [parsers.read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html) ? Did you try to use it - make some experiments with arguments ?

Comment: Yes, I did. That is how I found the function. I did experiment with it that is how I found this issue.

Comment: To clarify I can't use dtype because I do not know what the header names will be until I read in the file.

Answer (score 1):

In general cases where you can't know the dtypes or column names of a CSV ahead of time, using a CSV sniffer can be helpful.

```
import csv
[...] 
dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(f.read(1024))
f.seek(0)

frame = pandas.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), dialect=dialect)
```

Comment: I have to be able to use unicode so I can't use python csv (I am using python 2.7). but close!! I could certainly make use of a Unicode version of that

Comment: Haven't tried this, but looks promising: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10275281/2907617