# How to retrieve my unicode from the unicode byte representation

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, unicode, character-encoding

I have an unicode string `κανω` but due to some preprocessing from some other software that I can't change it becomes a literal string `'\u03ba\u03b1\u03bd\u03c9'` instead of `u'\u03ba\u03b1\u03bd\u03c9'`.

**How could I change `'\u03ba\u03b1\u03bd\u03c9'` back to `u'\u03ba\u03b1\u03bd\u03c9'`?**

I've tried:

```
>>> x = '\u03ba\u03b1\u03bd\u03c9'
>>> print x
\u03ba\u03b1\u03bd\u03c9
>>> print x.decode('utf8')
\u03ba\u03b1\u03bd\u03c9
>>> print x.encode('utf8')
\u03ba\u03b1\u03bd\u03c9
>>> print unicode(x)
\u03ba\u03b1\u03bd\u03c9
```

I cannot possibly go to each string output and add the `u'...'`, i.e. I need to avoid doing this:

```
>>> x = u'\u03ba\u03b1\u03bd\u03c9'
>>> print x
κανω
```

Comment: There are many string formats that include `\u` escapes and if you use a decoder that doesn't match the encoder (eg if you decoded a JSON string with the Python-specific `unicode-escape`) then you are likely to end up with mangled results for some corner cases. Suggest you find out more specifics about the format... for example how does it output a backslash, or a newline, a zero byte, or a character in the range 0080–00FF?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need [`'unicode_escape'`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#python-specific-encodings) (Produce a string that is suitable as Unicode literal in Python source code) as its encoding  :

```
>>> s='\u03ba\u03b1\u03bd\u03c9'
>>> print unicode(s,'unicode_escape')
κανω
```