# python's encoding difference

Tags: python, encoding

```
# my scraper script file
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import webdriver
import csv

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("http://web.com")

f = open("result.csv", 'w')
writer = csv.writer(f)
```

then the first method

```
element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("xpath_addr")
temp = [element.get_attribute("innerHTML").encode("utf-8")]
print temp                # ['\xec\x84\something\xa8']
writer.writerow(temp)
```

this results in the right csv file with my language.(e.g. 한글)

but the second case, which I think just a little different

```
element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("xpath_addr")
temp = element.get_attribute("innerHTML").encode("utf-8")
print temp                # "한글" 
writer.writerow(temp)
```

then the csv file is full of non-character things. What makes this difference? print also gets different results but why? (It must be the problem because of my little knowledge about encoding)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, `writerow` interface is expecting a list-like object, so the first snippet is correct for this interface.  But in your second snippet, the method is assuming that the string you have passed as an argument is a list - and iterating it as such - which is probably not what you wanted.  You could try `writerow([temp])` and see that it should match the output of the first case.

Secondly, I want to warn you that Python [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module is [notorious for headaches with unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846135/python-csv-library-with-unicode-utf-8-support-that-just-works), basically it's unsupoorted.  Try using [`unicodecsv`](https://github.com/jdunck/python-unicodecsv) as a drop-in replacement for the csv module if you need to support unicode.  Then you won't need to encode the strings before writing them to file, you just write the unicode objects directly and let the library handle the encoding.

Comment: You're right it's working, thanks! I should have been cautious about what object is expected. Thank you for the tip(newbie like me would use csv module forever without your tip) unicodecsv also!