# A resilient, actually working CSV implementation for non-ascii?

Tags: python, unicode, encoding

[Update] Appreciate the answers and input all around, but **working code** would be most welcome. If you can supply code that can read the sample files you are king (or queen).

[Update 2] Thanks for the excellent answers and discussion. What I need to do with these is to read them in, parse them, and save parts of them in Django model instances. I believe that means converting them from their native encoding to unicode so Django can deal with them, right?

There are [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1846135/python-csv-library-with-unicode-utf-8-support-that-just-works) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3479961/python-csv-unicodedecodeerror) on Stackoverflow already on the subject of non-ascii python CSV reading, but the solutions shown there and in the python documentation don't work with the input files I'm trying.

The gist of the solution seems to be to encode('utf-8') the input to the CSV reader and unicode(item, 'utf-8') the output of the reader. However, this runs into UnicodeDecodeError issues (see above questions):

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa3 in position 8: unexpected
```

The input file is not necessarily in utf8; it can be ISO-8859-1, cp1251, or just about anything else.

So, the question: what's a resilient, cross-encoding capable way to read CSV files in Python?

The root of the issue seems to be that the CSV module is a C extension; is there a pure-python CSV reading module?

If not, is there a way to confidently detect the encoding of the input file so that it can be processed?

Basically I'm looking for a bullet proof way to read (and hopefully write) CSV files in any encoding.

Here are two sample files: [European](http://parand.com/tmp/CSV/sample-euro.csv), [Russian](http://parand.com/tmp/CSV/sample-russian.csv).

And here's the recommended solution failing:

```
Python 2.6.4 (r264:75821M, Oct 27 2009, 19:48:32)
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import csv
>>> def unicode_csv_reader(unicode_csv_data, dialect=csv.excel, **kwargs):
...     # csv.py doesn't do Unicode; encode temporarily as UTF-8:
...     csv_reader = csv.reader(utf_8_encoder(unicode_csv_data),
...                             dialect=dialect, **kwargs)
...     for row in csv_reader:
...         # decode UTF-8 back to Unicode, cell by cell:
...         yield [unicode(cell, 'utf-8') for cell in row]
...
>>> def utf_8_encoder(unicode_csv_data):
...     for line in unicode_csv_data:
...         yield line.encode('utf-8')
...
>>> r = unicode_csv_reader(file('sample-euro.csv').read().split('\n'))
>>> line = r.next()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in unicode_csv_reader
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in utf_8_encoder
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xf8 in position 14: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> r = unicode_csv_reader(file('sample-russian.csv').read().split('\n'))
>>> line = r.next()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 5, in unicode_csv_reader
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in utf_8_encoder
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 28: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: You have to know the encoding else you may get invalid data. If you want to guess you should at least have a way to determine if you guessed correctly - "didn't throw an error" says nothing about the integrity.

Comment: working code supplied; see my updated answer.

Comment: You must tell us WHAT do you need to do with those strings. Because if you just need to read them, then split/merge/total them with no  string digesting/processing and then just output that to another file, you don't need to do ANY decoding in most common cases. So what do you need to do to the strings from CSV further?

Comment: Thanks for the clarifications in updates. It seems clear now your problem has nothing to do with CSV files (since the CSV parser will work just fine on most popular encodings) and everything to do with detecting encoding of a text (byte stream). There is no general or bullet-proof solution to that, so you should consider user hints for that, be it GUI or command line params.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are attempting to apply a solution to a **different** problem. Note this:

def utf_8_encoder(**unicode_csv_data**)

You are feeding it `str` objects.

The problems with reading your non-ASCII CSV files is that you don't know the encoding and you don't know the delimiter. If you do know the encoding (and it's an ASCII-based encoding (e.g. cp125x, any East Asian encoding, UTF-8, *not* UTF-16, *not* UTF-32)), and the delimiter, this will work:

```
for row in csv.reader("foo.csv", delimiter=known_delimiter):
   row = [item.decode(encoding) for item in row]
```

Your sample_euro.csv looks like cp1252 with comma delimiter. The Russian one looks like cp1251 with semicolon delimiter. By the way, it seems from the contents that you will also need to determine what date format is being used and maybe the currency also -- the Russian example has money amounts followed by a space and the Cyrillic abbreviation for "roubles".

Note carefully: Resist all attempts to persuade you that you have files encoded in ISO-8859-1. They are encoded in cp1252.

**Update** in response to comment """If I understand what you're saying I must know the encoding in order for this to work? In the general case I won't know the encoding and based on the other answer guessing the encoding is very difficult, so I'm out of luck?"""

You must know the encoding for **ANY** file-reading exercise to work.

Guessing the encoding correctly all the time for any encoding in any size file is not very difficult -- it's impossible. However restricting the scope to csv files saved out of Excel or Open Office in the user's locale's default encoding, and of a reasonable size, it's not such a big task. I'd suggest giving [chardet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet) a try; it guesses `windows-1252` for your euro file and `windows-1251` for your Russian file -- a fantastic achievement given their tiny size.

**Update 2** in response to """**working code** would be most welcome"""

Working code (Python 2.x):

```
from chardet.universaldetector import UniversalDetector
chardet_detector = UniversalDetector()

def charset_detect(f, chunk_size=4096):
    global chardet_detector
    chardet_detector.reset()
    while 1:
        chunk = f.read(chunk_size)
        if not chunk: break
        chardet_detector.feed(chunk)
        if chardet_detector.done: break
    chardet_detector.close()
    return chardet_detector.result

# Exercise for the reader: replace the above with a class

import csv    
import sys
from pprint import pprint

pathname = sys.argv[1]
delim = sys.argv[2] # allegedly known
print "delim=%r pathname=%r" % (delim, pathname)

with open(pathname, 'rb') as f:
    cd_result = charset_detect(f)
    encoding = cd_result['encoding']
    confidence = cd_result['confidence']
    print "chardet: encoding=%s confidence=%.3f" % (encoding, confidence)
    # insert actions contingent on encoding and confidence here
    f.seek(0)
    csv_reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=delim)
    for bytes_row in csv_reader:
        unicode_row = [x.decode(encoding) for x in bytes_row]
        pprint(unicode_row)
```

Output 1:

```
delim=',' pathname='sample-euro.csv'
chardet: encoding=windows-1252 confidence=0.500
[u'31-01-11',
 u'Overf\xf8rsel utland',
 u'UTLBET; ID 9710032001647082',
 u'1990.00',
 u'']
[u'31-01-11',
 u'Overf\xf8ring',
 u'OVERF\xd8RING MELLOM EGNE KONTI',
 u'5750.00',
 u';']
```

Output 2:

```
delim=';' pathname='sample-russian.csv'
chardet: encoding=windows-1251 confidence=0.602
[u'-',
 u'04.02.2011 23:20',
 u'300,00\xa0\u0440\u0443\u0431.',
 u'',
 u'\u041c\u0422\u0421',
 u'']
[u'-',
 u'04.02.2011 23:15',
 u'450,00\xa0\u0440\u0443\u0431.',
 u'',
 u'\u041e\u043f\u043b\u0430\u0442\u0430 Interzet',
 u'']
[u'-',
 u'13.01.2011 02:05',
 u'100,00\xa0\u0440\u0443\u0431.',
 u'',
 u'\u041c\u0422\u0421 kolombina',
 u'']
```

**Update 3** What is the source of these files? If they are being "saved as CSV" from Excel or OpenOffice Calc or Gnumeric, you could avoid the whole encoding drama by having them saved as "Excel 97-2003 Workbook (*.xls)" and use [xlrd](http://www.python-excel.org) to read them. This would also save the hassles of having to inspect each csv file to determine the delimiter (comma vs semicolon), date format (31-01-11 vs 04.02.2011), and "decimal point" (5750.00 vs 450,00) -- *all those differences presumably being created by saving as CSV*. [Dis]claimer: I'm the author of `xlrd`.

Comment: Thanks John. I'm not worried about the date format and delimiter, those are easy enough to figure out. If I understand what you're saying I must know the encoding in order for this to work? In the general case I won't know the encoding and based on the other answer guessing the encoding is very difficult, so I'm out of luck?

Comment: John, great stuff, thanks very much. The discussion is great so I'll leave it open a little while more.

Comment: @Parand: Some more discussion; see my Update 3.

Comment: Thanks for the xlrd pointer, I'd checked the entire suite out some time ago (as well as the OpenOffice Java libraries via Jython). Unfortunately the CSV files are not always from Excel.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if you've already tried this, but in the [example](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#examples) section for the official Python documentation for the csv module, you'll find a pair of classes; `UnicodeReader` and `UnicodeWriter`. They worked fine for me so far.

Correctly detecting the encoding of a file seems to be a very hard problem. You can read the discussion in [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436220/python-is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-encoding-of-text-file).

Comment: The example from the docs fails. I've updated the question with the failing code and sample files.

Comment: -1 UnicodeReader reads `unicode` objects. The OP has `str` objects.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the wrong thing in your code by trying to `.encode('utf-8')`, you should be decoding it instead. And btw, `unicode(bytestr, 'utf-8')` == `bytestr.decode('utf-8')`

But most importantly, WHY are you trying to decode the strings?

Sounds a bit absurd but you can actually work with those CSV without caring whether they are cp1251, cp1252 or utf-8. The beauty of it all is that the regional characters are >0x7F and utf-8 too, uses sequences of >0x7F characters to represent non-ASCII symbols.

Since the separators CSV cares about (be it , or ; or \n) are within ASCII, its work won't be affected by the encoding used (as long as it is one-byte or utf-8!).

Important thing to note is that you should give to Python 2.x `csv` module files opened in `binary` mode - that is either 'rb' or 'wb' - because of the peculiar way it was implemented.

Comment: """So long as it is one-byte or utf-8""": Please explain why you think that multibyte encodings like gbk, gb18030, big5, shift-jis, euc-jp, euc-kr, johab etc wouldn't work.

Comment: @John Machin: i did not say it won't work for the encodings you enumerate. It may or it may not work, i don't know anything on them. What i know and i said is that it will work with one-byte encodings and utf-8 - and i think that is the part relevant to the OP

Comment: PS. i just skimmed wikipedia pages on the mb encodings you enumerate (except johab, which i could not find) and it seems *likely* it will work with them too because their 2-byte characters are encoded in pairs of the kind (0x80..0xFF) (0x40..0xFF), thus avoiding confusion with the lower half (<0x40) of ASCII

Comment: You DID say it wouldn't work ... "so long as X" means "only if X", NOT "if X".

Comment: @John Machin: I am not a native speaker of English, so i may have made a mistake, of course. But looking at http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/so_long_as = *Depending upon some condition or requirement; provided that; if, assuming; as long as* seems to be what i meant. And when i said "Y as long as X", i indeed mean "Y provided that X", "Y, assuming X", "Y, if X". Notice that it is not "Y if and only if X"; it is implication and not equivalence?

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is impossible. There is no way to write a program in any language that will accept input in an unknown encoding and correctly convert it to Unicode internal representation.

You have to find a way to tell the application which encoding to use.

It is possible to recognize many, but not all, encodingshardet but it really depends on what the content of the files is and whether there are enough data points. This is similar to the issue of correctly decoding filenames on network servers. When a file is created on a network server, there is no way to tell the server what encoding is used, so if you have a folder with names in multiple encodings they are guaranteed to look odd to some, if not all, users and different files will seem odd.

However, don't give up. Try the chardet encoding detector mentioned in this question: https://serverfault.com/questions/82821/how-to-tell-the-language-encoding-of-a-filename-on-linux
and if you are lucky, you won't get many failures.