# UnicodeEncodeError when creating .csv file

Tags: python, csv, urllib2

I am trying to create a .csv file with data that I have stored into a list from Twitter search API.  I have saved the last 100 tweets with a keyword that I chose (in this case 'reddit') and I am trying to save each tweet into a cell in a .csv file.  My code is below and I am returning an error that is:

`UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`

If anyone knows what I can do to fix this it would be greatly appreciated!

```
import sys
import os


import urllib
import urllib2
import json
from pprint import pprint
import csv

import sentiment_analyzer

import codecs

class Twitter:
    def __init__(self):
        self.api_url = {}
        self.api_url['search'] = 'http://search.twitter.com/search.json?'

    def search(self, params):

        url = self.make_url(params, apitype='search')
        data = json.loads(urllib2.urlopen(url).read().decode('utf-8').encode('ascii',     'ignore'))

        txt = []
        for obj in data['results']:
            txt.append(obj['text'])

        return '\n'.join(txt)

    def make_url(self, params, apitype='search'):


        baseurl = self.api_url[apitype] 
        return baseurl + urllib.urlencode(params)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        query = sys.argv[1]
    except IndexError:
        query = 'reddit'

    t = Twitter()

    s = sentiment_analyzer.SentimentAnalyzer()

    params = {'q': query, 'result_type': 'recent', 'rpp': 100}

    urlName = t.make_url(params)
    print urlName
    txt = t.search(params)

    print s.analyze_text(txt)

    myfile = open('reddit.csv', 'wb')
    wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    wr.writerow(txt)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the Python 2 documentation for the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv) module:

> **Note**
>
> This version of the csv module doesn’t support Unicode input. Also,
>   there are currently some issues regarding ASCII NUL characters.
>   Accordingly, all input should be UTF-8 or printable ASCII to be safe;
>   see the examples in section [Examples](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#csv-examples).

That said, you can probably parse the `.csv` file yourself without too much difficulty using Python's built-in Unicode string support -- there's also this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5020446/python-a-resilient-actually-working-csv-implementation-for-non-ascii).

Comment: +1. The cited Examples even seems to have something for exactly this case.

Answer (score 0):

You realize this kind of problem is exactly the reason behind Python 3.

I'm assuming you have a good reason for insisting on Python 2 instead of Python 3. Maybe you're trying to deploy this on a hosting site that gives you Python 2.7 and that's it, or you're running an ancient OS that Python 3 hasn't been ported to, or whatever.

But if not, just switch. The `csv` module in Python 2 doesn't handle Unicode, and has some weird quirks even when you do encode/decode explicitly; the one in Python 3 is all Unicode, and relies on the underlying `file` object to deal with the underlying charset.

You will need to change a couple of things, but `2to3 -w twitter.py` will take care of all of it except possibly removing the `b` from `open('reddit.csv', 'wb')`.