# Why does Python String concatenation work with Russian text but string.format() does not

Tags: python, csv, character-encoding, windows-1251

I'm trying to parse (and escape) rows of a CSV file that is stored in [Windows-1251](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1251) character encoding.  Using [this excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5021445/16959) to deal with this encoding I've ended up with this one line to test the output, for some reason this works:

```
print(row[0]+','+row[1])
```

Outputting:

```
Тяжелый Уборщик Обязанности,1 литр
```

While this line doesn't work:

```
print("{0},{1}".format(*row))
```

Outputting this error:

```
Name,Variant

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Russian.py", line 26, in <module>
    print("{0},{1}".format(*row))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 2-3: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Here are the first 2 lines of the CSV:

```
Name,Variant
Тяжелый Уборщик Обязанности,1 литр
```

and in case it helps, here is the full source of Russian.py:

```
import csv
import cgi
from chardet.universaldetector import UniversalDetector
chardet_detector = UniversalDetector()

def charset_detect(f, chunk_size=4096):
    global chardet_detector
    chardet_detector.reset()
    while 1:
        chunk = f.read(chunk_size)
        if not chunk: break
        chardet_detector.feed(chunk)
        if chardet_detector.done: break
    chardet_detector.close()
    return chardet_detector.result

with open('Russian.csv') as csv_file:
    cd_result = charset_detect(csv_file)
    encoding = cd_result['encoding']
    csv_file.seek(0)
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file)
    for bytes_row in csv_reader:
        row = [x.decode(encoding) for x in bytes_row]
        if len(row) >= 6:
            #print(row[0]+','+row[1])
            print("{0},{1}".format(*row))
```

Comment: Because you got lucky. Always treat text as Unicode, except at the edges (decode at ingest, encode when producing your final output).

Comment: My understanding is that `row = [x.decode(encoding) for x in bytes_row]` is producing an array of unicode strings, am I mistaken?

Comment: `print(u"{0},{1}".format(*row))`, you are trying to to encode as ascii using str.format.

Comment: My mind is blown. I am eagerly awaiting the submission of @PadraicCunningham's comment as an answer.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Thanks for destroying my dreams when I thought I got the answer and was so proud of myself!

Comment: @Zizouz212, lol, well there is still no answer so you could still be proud and add an answer!

Comment: @Zizouz212, this is true, the answer just as to be correct and first.  Something tells me Padraic Cunningham can weather a few stolen answers if you are trying to build up your Python rep :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The strings in your list were likely already unicode, so you didn't get an issue.

```
print(row[0]+','+row[1])
Тяжелый Уборщик Обязанности,1 литр
```

But here we are trying to add unicode to a normal string! That's why you get the `UnicodeEncodeError`.

```
print("{0},{1}".format(*row))
```

So just change it to:

```
print(u"{0}, {1}".format(*row))
```

Comment: This doesn't really explain why the first version works. It's still adding `unicode` to `str`, then adding the result to `unicode`. [Martijn Pieters' answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30469184/908494) explains why that's OK (because in this case it ends up decoding the `','`).

Answer (score 3):

You are using `str.format()` which converts `unicode()` to `str()` implicitly. It has to do so to be able to interpolate values into the template provided.

Use `unicode.format()` instead:

```
print(u"{0},{1}".format(*row))
```

Note the `u` before the format literal. `unicode.format()` has to *decode* `str` inputs to fit in the resulting Unicode output.

Concatenation on the other hand can implicitly *decode* to produce a final `unicode()` object result. Had your `','` value contained non-ASCII bytes that implicit decoding would also fail.

Moral of the story: use Unicode string literals throughout your code when handling text.

Answer (score 0):

the `+` operand works fine between a `unicode` string and an `str` string. On the other hand, `str.format` doesn't accept `unicode` strings as parameters.

Thus, you can simply replace the problematic line with the following:

```
print(u"{0},{1}".format(*row))
```

That should do the trick.

Comment: This is wrong. `str.format` _does_ accept `unicode` strings as parameters; it just `encode`s them. And `+` only "works fine" between `unicode` and `str` in the same sense—because it `encode`s one or `decode`s the other.