# Trouble with UTF-8 CSV input in Python

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8

This seems like it should be an easy fix, but so far a solution has eluded me. I have a single column csv file with non-ascii chars saved in utf-8 that I want to read in and store in a list. I'm attempting to follow the principle of the ["Unicode Sandwich"](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) and decode upon reading the file in:

```
import codecs
import csv

with codecs.open('utf8file.csv', 'rU', encoding='utf-8') as file:
input_file = csv.reader(file, delimiter=",", quotechar='|')
list = []
for row in input_file:
    list.extend(row)
```

This produces the dread 'codec can't encode characters in position, ordinal not in range(128)' error.

I've also tried adapting a solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904041/reading-a-utf8-csv-file-with-python), which returns a similar error

```
def unicode_csv_reader(utf8_data, dialect=csv.excel, **kwargs):
    csv_reader = csv.reader(utf8_data, dialect=dialect, **kwargs)
    for row in csv_reader:
        yield [unicode(cell, 'utf-8') for cell in row]

filename = 'inputs\encode.csv'
reader = unicode_csv_reader(open(filename))
target_list = []
for field1 in reader:
    target_list.extend(field1)
```

A very similar solution adapted from the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#examples) returns the same error.

```
def unicode_csv_reader(utf8_data, dialect=csv.excel):
    csv_reader = csv.reader(utf_8_encoder(utf8_data), dialect)
    for row in csv_reader:
        yield [unicode(cell, 'utf-8') for cell in row]

def utf_8_encoder(unicode_csv_data):
    for line in unicode_csv_data:
    yield line.encode('utf-8')

filename = 'inputs\encode.csv'
reader = unicode_csv_reader(open(filename))
target_list = []
for field1 in reader:
    target_list.extend(field1)
```

Clearly I'm missing something. Most of the questions that I've seen regarding this problem seem to predate Python 2.7, so an update here might be useful.

Comment: The error message suggests it could be trying to decode the data as ASCII...

Comment: Your second example works for me, maybe you have broken csv module, I suggest you upgrade your python? Or maybe the error is elsewhere

Comment: It sounds like your original CSV file isn't encoded as UTF-8 - can you confirm it is? Maybe it's UTF-16LE or something, or some other language-specific coding. You can use the chardet module to detect encoding.

Comment: @Ansari it is my understanding that it's impossible to reliably detect encoding based on only the file. I re-saved a copy of the file in utf-8 just now, retested, and got the same result  so for our purposes here we can rule that out.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala My version of Python came from a clean Windows install a few weeks ago, version is 2.7.3.

Comment: @LevLevitsky that's certain possible, the full error message is "UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 1-2: ordinal not in range(128)". Does that give you any more insight?

Comment: Fair enough - why don't you pinpoint the character at which it is failing? Print out some information about which lines are processed and see which line and character it is failing at. When I had this error it was because of a few stray characters that were mis-encoded.

Comment: @acpigeon: actually detecting UTF-8 is very easy. If you read the whole file you should be able to decode it as UTF-8, as in open('encode.csv').read().decode('UTF-8'). If it does not fail then with almost 100.0 % certainty it can be said that it is either plain ASCII, UTF-8, or ASCII characters as UTF-16, or UTF-32 ;)

Comment: Print statements fail at the first occurrence of a non-ascii character. In my sample file, this would be 'Ú'.

Comment: But this kind of error means that you are converting an unicode object to a str

Comment: Ah, so you're not really making a sandwich. You get Unicode, but at some point Python tries to silently convert it to ASCII.

Comment: print does that always :D and that surely is discussed all the time in stackoverflow

Comment: @acpigeon you never said you were printing it. Encode it as utf-8, and it will be printed right.

Comment: Not printing in any of my implementations, just to test a point @Ansari made. Correction, the test print statements work up until seeing a non-ascii char, at which point the error is triggered. Sorry!

Comment: That sounds right, unless you do something like `print unistr.encode('utf-8')`. Apart from that, could you show the full traceback for the code in the question?

Comment: File "encoding.py", line 53, in <module> for row in input_file:
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 1-2: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: where is the error happening? can you post the traceback?

Comment: actually, have you tried it without doing anything special at all? just `csv.reader(the_file)`?

Comment: That error message is from your FIRST code snippet, which is guaranteed not to work. Also it's at line 53 in your file -- you are NOT showing all your code (bad idea). Show the full traceback and error message from your SECOND snippet.

Comment: Have you tried to [specify the `b` flag in `open`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#module-contents)?

Comment: Sorry John, trying to isolate the problem code snippet within a larger script so I've commented out the irrelevant chunks. Tried moving just the second snippet to a test file and the error seems to go away. I'm going to try rebuilding my original script piece by piece and will update with the results.

Comment: Use https://pypi.python.org/pypi/unicodecsv/0.14.1

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your first snippet won't work. You are feeding unicode data to the csv reader, which (as documented) can't handle it.

Your 2nd and 3rd snippets are confused. Something like the following is all that you need:

```
f = open('your_utf8_encoded_file.csv', 'rb')
reader = csv.reader(f)
for utf8_row in reader:
    unicode_row = [x.decode('utf8') for x in utf8_row]
    print unicode_row
```

Comment: This works. Not sure exactly what in my original script was causing the problem, but such is life. Thanks.

Answer (score 12):

At it fails from the first char to read, you may have a BOM. Use `codecs.open('utf8file.csv', 'rU', encoding='utf-8-sig')` if your file is UTF8 and has a BOM at the beginning.

Answer (score -2):

I'd suggest trying just:

```
input_file = csv.reader(open('utf8file.csv', 'r'), delimiter=",", quotechar='|')
```

or

```
input_file = csv.reader(open('utf8file.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=",", quotechar='|')
```

csv should be unicode aware, and it should just work.

Comment: it is specifically NOT unicode aware, however neither does your example use unicode.

Comment: there is no such thing as "utf-8 aware"