# Handling non-standard American English Characters and Symbols in a CSV, using Python

Tags: python, csv

I have a list of store names, with a few thousand names, some of which have non-standard American English characters that are posing a problem.

For example, my input file looks like this:

```
store_name
yéché
Ázak
ótndle
```

I want the output file to actually look like this (I think Googledocs made this happen, btw):

```
store_name  new_store_name 
yéché       yÃ©chÃ©
Ázak        Ãzak
ótndle      Ã³tndle
```

There are only about 10 such rules that convert the non-standard American English character into this format, so I went through and did control f in excel to make them. But I'd like to be able in the future to do things like this computationally, and was just wondering if there is a quick way of doing this using Python.  To be clear, what I want to do is make:

```
é become Ã©
Á become Ãi
```

Comment: Wait, you are *trying* to mangle data and do encoding wrong?

Comment: Are you sure this isn't a change of encoding that you're seeing this way?

Comment: I think saving UTF-8 would work out better. But the problem you're encountering is most likely to do with MS Office's CP 1252 encoding which is funky to begin with

Comment: Anyway, your language indicates you should read [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: Kind of. So we put an excel file as a google doc, but then when we took it back into excel the words had the mangled names. But we assigned ID's to the mangled names, so now we want to connect the mangled name to the original name, so I thought if I make a csv file with the original name in one column, and the mangled name next to it, that we could then get the ID's that we assigned.

Comment: How about you understand and fix the encoding issues instead?

Comment: @user1590499 that sounds like GDocs is reading Office's CP-1252 encoding as either ASCII or UTF-8, which often causes this kind of jumbled-ness.

Comment: Thanks guys. I'm just reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221176/excel-to-csv-with-utf8-encoding now, thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: You might also be interested in this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/904041/reading-a-utf8-csv-file-with-python

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [decode and encode](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html#module-codecs):

```
print a
péché
Álak
óundle

print a.decode('latin9').encode('utf8'),
pÃ©chÃ©
Ãlak
Ã³undle
```

I had to do the reverse...

Comment: Thanks! This was very easy to use jjust by writing a for loop, using dictReader/dictWriter and the line you put above. I have a quick question if you don't mind, how did you know that my text was latin9? I just read http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html per a user's kind suggestion, but I am just wondering how you knew the text was latin9?

Comment: It was what I had to use to go the other way. I tried the list in the docs until I found one that worked. My project included making a rtf file from python. I recognized the 'mangled' chars.

Comment: Thanks man. Most of them seem to work but I get an error with: â€™. The error is:   File "C:\Python27\lib\encodings\iso8859_15.py", line 12, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u2019' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: In the link you have the standard encodings. You can expect complications when anything is non-english. You have to become good at it so study and experiment a lot...

Comment: Thanks man. I figured that I need to convert it to IE7, but unfortunately that's not in the Python docs list as far as i can see...

Comment: found a solution: just put a bunch of if-statements in my code to handle the exceptions to the conversion from utf8 to latin9...

Answer (score 17):

Your issue is most likely with the MS Office suite's CP-1252 "Windows Unicode" encoding. If you read it as either ASCII or UTF, you'll get funky characters.

You can do two things:

1. Force MS Office to use another encoding. Some of the Office programs support it, and some do not.
2. Rewrite the file after MS Office saves it.

To do 2 in python, you can use something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python -u
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

##
## cp1252 to UTF-8 decoder
##
## An expansion of the code found at http://effbot.org/zone/unicode-gremlins.htm
##



"""Converts stupid microsoft Windows 1252 characters to actual unicode,
so that the rest of the world can still use it.
"""
import re

## small collection:
#~ cp1252 = {
    #~ # from http://www.microsoft.com/typography/unicode/1252.htm
    #~ u"\x80": u"\u20AC", # EURO SIGN
    #~ u"\x82": u"\u201A", # SINGLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK
    #~ u"\x83": u"\u0192", # LATIN SMALL LETTER F WITH HOOK
    #~ u"\x84": u"\u201E", # DOUBLE LOW-9 QUOTATION MARK
    #~ u"\x85": u"\u2026", # HORIZONTAL ELLIPSIS
    #~ u"\x86": u"\u2020", # DAGGER
    #~ u"\x87": u"\u2021", # DOUBLE DAGGER
    #~ u"\x88": u"\u02C6", # MODIFIER LETTER CIRCUMFLEX ACCENT
    #~ u"\x89": u"\u2030", # PER MILLE SIGN
    #~ u"\x8A": u"\u0160", # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER S WITH CARON
    #~ u"\x8B": u"\u2039", # SINGLE LEFT-POINTING ANGLE QUOTATION MARK
    #~ u"\x8C": u"\u0152", # LATIN CAPITAL LIGATURE OE
    #~ u"\x8E": u"\u017D", # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Z WITH CARON
    #~ u"\x91": u"\u2018", # LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK
    #~ u"\x92": u"\u2019", # RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK
    #~ u"\x93": u"\u201C", # LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK
    #~ u"\x94": u"\u201D", # RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK
    #~ u"\x95": u"\u2022", # BULLET
    #~ u"\x96": u"\u2013", # EN DASH
    #~ u"\x97": u"\u2014", # EM DASH
    #~ u"\x98": u"\u02DC", # SMALL TILDE
    #~ u"\x99": u"\u2122", # TRADE MARK SIGN
    #~ u"\x9A": u"\u0161", # LATIN SMALL LETTER S WITH CARON
    #~ u"\x9B": u"\u203A", # SINGLE RIGHT-POINTING ANGLE QUOTATION MARK
    #~ u"\x9C": u"\u0153", # LATIN SMALL LIGATURE OE
    #~ u"\x9E": u"\u017E", # LATIN SMALL LETTER Z WITH CARON
    #~ u"\x9F": u"\u0178", # LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Y WITH DIAERESIS
#~ }


## bigger collection:
cp1252 = {

    u"\x80": u"\u20AC",    #            e282ac
    u"\x81": u"\uFFFD",    #    `   ?    efbfbd
    u"\x82": u"\u201A",    #            e2809a
    u"\x83": u"\u0192",    #    à   à   c692
    u"\x84": u"\u201E",    #    Ġ   Ġ   e2809e
    u"\x85": u"\u2026",    #    Š   Š   e280a6
    u"\x86": u"\u2020",    #    Ơ   Ơ   e280a0
    u"\x87": u"\u2021",    #    Ǡ   Ǡ   e280a1
    u"\x88": u"\u02C6",    #    Ƞ   Ƞ   cb86
    u"\x89": u"\u2030",    #    ɠ   ɠ   e280b0
    u"\x8a": u"\u0160",    #    ʠ   ʠ   c5a0
    u"\x8b": u"\u2039",    #    ˠ   ˠ   e280b9
    u"\x8c": u"\u0152",    #    ̠   ̠   c592
    u"\x8d": u"\uFFFD",    #    ͠   ?    efbfbd
    u"\x8e": u"\u017D",    #    Π   Π   c5bd
    u"\x8f": u"\uFFFD",    #    Ϡ   ?    efbfbd
    u"\x90": u"\uFFFD",    #    Р   ?    efbfbd
    u"\x91": u"\u2018",    #    Ѡ   Ѡ   e28098
    u"\x92": u"\u2019",    #    Ҡ   Ҡ   e28099
    u"\x93": u"\u201C",    #    Ӡ   Ӡ   e2809c
    u"\x94": u"\u201D",    #    Ԡ   Ԡ   e2809d
    u"\x95": u"\u2022",    #    ՠ   ՠ   e280a2
    u"\x96": u"\u2013",    #    ֠   ֠   e28093
    u"\x97": u"\u2014",    #    נ   נ   e28094
    u"\x98": u"\u02DC",    #    ؠ   ؠ   cb9c
    u"\x99": u"\u2122",    #    ٠   ٠   e284a2
    u"\x9a": u"\u0161",    #    ڠ   ڠ   c5a1
    u"\x9b": u"\u203A",    #    ۠   ۠   e280ba
    u"\x9c": u"\u0153",    #    ܠ   ܠ   c593
    u"\x9d": u"\uFFFD",    #    ݠ   ?    efbfbd
    u"\x9e": u"\u017E",    #    ޠ   ޠ   c5be
    u"\x9f": u"\u0178",    #    ߠ   ߠ   c5b8
    u"\xa0": u"\u00A0",    #             c2a0
    u"\xa1": u"\u00A1",    #    `   `   c2a1
    u"\xa2": u"\u00A2",    #            c2a2
    u"\xa3": u"\u00A3",    #    à   à   c2a3
    u"\xa4": u"\u00A4",    #    Ġ   Ġ   c2a4
    u"\xa5": u"\u00A5",    #    Š   Š   c2a5
    u"\xa6": u"\u00A6",    #    Ơ   Ơ   c2a6
    u"\xa7": u"\u00A7",    #    Ǡ   Ǡ   c2a7
    u"\xa8": u"\u00A8",    #    Ƞ   Ƞ   c2a8
    u"\xa9": u"\u00A9",    #    ɠ   ɠ   c2a9
    u"\xaa": u"\u00AA",    #    ʠ   ʠ   c2aa
    u"\xab": u"\u00AB",    #    ˠ   ˠ   c2ab
    u"\xac": u"\u00AC",    #    ̠   ̠   c2ac
    u"\xad": u"\u00AD",    #    ͠   ͠   c2ad
    u"\xae": u"\u00AE",    #    Π   Π   c2ae
    u"\xaf": u"\u00AF",    #    Ϡ   Ϡ   c2af
    u"\xb0": u"\u00B0",    #    Р   Р   c2b0
    u"\xb1": u"\u00B1",    #    Ѡ   Ѡ   c2b1
    u"\xb2": u"\u00B2",    #    Ҡ   Ҡ   c2b2
    u"\xb3": u"\u00B3",    #    Ӡ   Ӡ   c2b3
    u"\xb4": u"\u00B4",    #    Ԡ   Ԡ   c2b4
    u"\xb5": u"\u00B5",    #    ՠ   ՠ   c2b5
    u"\xb6": u"\u00B6",    #    ֠   ֠   c2b6
    u"\xb7": u"\u00B7",    #    נ   נ   c2b7
    u"\xb8": u"\u00B8",    #    ؠ   ؠ   c2b8
    u"\xb9": u"\u00B9",    #    ٠   ٠   c2b9
    u"\xba": u"\u00BA",    #    ڠ   ڠ   c2ba
    u"\xbb": u"\u00BB",    #    ۠   ۠   c2bb
    u"\xbc": u"\u00BC",    #    ܠ   ܠ   c2bc
    u"\xbd": u"\u00BD",    #    ݠ   ݠ   c2bd
    u"\xbe": u"\u00BE",    #    ޠ   ޠ   c2be
    u"\xbf": u"\u00BF",    #    ߠ   ߠ   c2bf
    u"\xc0": u"\u00C0",    #            c380
    u"\xc1": u"\u00C1",    #    `   `   c381
    u"\xc2": u"\u00C2",    #            c382
    u"\xc3": u"\u00C3",    #    à   à   c383
    u"\xc4": u"\u00C4",    #    Ġ   Ġ   c384
    u"\xc5": u"\u00C5",    #    Š   Š   c385
    u"\xc6": u"\u00C6",    #    Ơ   Ơ   c386
    u"\xc7": u"\u00C7",    #    Ǡ   Ǡ   c387
    u"\xc8": u"\u00C8",    #    Ƞ   Ƞ   c388
    u"\xc9": u"\u00C9",    #    ɠ   ɠ   c389
    u"\xca": u"\u00CA",    #    ʠ   ʠ   c38a
    u"\xcb": u"\u00CB",    #    ˠ   ˠ   c38b
    u"\xcc": u"\u00CC",    #    ̠   ̠   c38c
    u"\xcd": u"\u00CD",    #    ͠   ͠   c38d
    u"\xce": u"\u00CE",    #    Π   Π   c38e
    u"\xcf": u"\u00CF",    #    Ϡ   Ϡ   c38f
    u"\xd0": u"\u00D0",    #    Р   Р   c390
    u"\xd1": u"\u00D1",    #    Ѡ   Ѡ   c391
    u"\xd2": u"\u00D2",    #    Ҡ   Ҡ   c392
    u"\xd3": u"\u00D3",    #    Ӡ   Ӡ   c393
    u"\xd4": u"\u00D4",    #    Ԡ   Ԡ   c394
    u"\xd5": u"\u00D5",    #    ՠ   ՠ   c395
    u"\xd6": u"\u00D6",    #    ֠   ֠   c396
    u"\xd7": u"\u00D7",    #    נ   נ   c397
    u"\xd8": u"\u00D8",    #    ؠ   ؠ   c398
    u"\xd9": u"\u00D9",    #    ٠   ٠   c399
    u"\xda": u"\u00DA",    #    ڠ   ڠ   c39a
    u"\xdb": u"\u00DB",    #    ۠   ۠   c39b
    u"\xdc": u"\u00DC",    #    ܠ   ܠ   c39c
    u"\xdd": u"\u00DD",    #    ݠ   ݠ   c39d
    u"\xde": u"\u00DE",    #    ޠ   ޠ   c39e
    u"\xdf": u"\u00DF",    #    ߠ   ߠ   c39f
    u"\xe0": u"\u00E0",    #    ࠠ  ࠠ  c3a0
    u"\xe1": u"\u00E1",    #    ᠠ  ᠠ  c3a1
    u"\xe2": u"\u00E2",    #    ⠠  ⠠  c3a2
    u"\xe3": u"\u00E3",    #    㠠  㠠  c3a3
    u"\xe4": u"\u00E4",    #    䠠  䠠  c3a4
    u"\xe5": u"\u00E5",    #    堠  堠  c3a5
    u"\xe6": u"\u00E6",    #    栠  栠  c3a6
    u"\xe7": u"\u00E7",    #    砠  砠  c3a7
    u"\xe8": u"\u00E8",    #    蠠  蠠  c3a8
    u"\xe9": u"\u00E9",    #    頠  頠  c3a9
    u"\xea": u"\u00EA",    #    ꠠ  ꠠ  c3aa
    u"\xeb": u"\u00EB",    #    렠  렠  c3ab
    u"\xec": u"\u00EC",    #    젠  젠  c3ac
    u"\xed": u"\u00ED",    #    ��  ��  c3ad
    u"\xee": u"\u00EE",    #        c3ae
    u"\xef": u"\u00EF",    #        c3af
    u"\xf0": u"\u00F0",    #      c3b0
    u"\xf1": u"\u00F1",    #      c3b1
    u"\xf2": u"\u00F2",    #      c3b2
    u"\xf3": u"\u00F3",    #      c3b3
    u"\xf4": u"\u00F4",    #    ���� ���� c3b4
    u"\xf5": u"\u00F5",    #    ���� ���� c3b5
    u"\xf6": u"\u00F6",    #    ���� ���� c3b6
    u"\xf7": u"\u00F7",    #    ���� ���� c3b7
    u"\xf8": u"\u00F8",    #      c3b8
    u"\xf9": u"\u00F9",    #      c3b9
    u"\xfa": u"\u00FA",    #      c3ba
    u"\xfb": u"\u00FB",    #      c3bb
    u"\xfc": u"\u00FC",    #    ���� ���� c3bc
    u"\xfd": u"\u00FD",    #    ���� ���� c3bd
    u"\xfe": u"\u00FE",    #    ���� ���� c3be
    u"\xff": u"\u00FF",    #    ���� ���� c3bf

}



def killgremlins(text):
    # map cp1252 gremlins to real unicode characters
    if re.search(u"[\x80-\xff]", text):
        def fixup(m):
            s = m.group(0)
            return cp1252.get(s, s)
        if isinstance(text, type("")):
            # make sure we have a unicode string
            text = unicode(text, "iso-8859-1")
        text = re.sub(u"[\x80-\xff]", fixup, text)
    return text
```

Comment: Thank you! I was beating my head against an encoding issue with an XML document when I really needed to do was load it into a parser and get all of the <foo> tags. I didn't care about perserving the integrity of the rest of the document. Your killgremlins was perfect!!