# Why am I getting odd characters?

Tags: python, encoding

Sorry if this isn't a reproducible example but I am guessing someone will know what to do when I describe the problem. The problem I have is that I am getting characters like "\xe2" "\x80" from a txt file that I am reading in the following way:

```
words = open("directory/file.txt","r")
liness = []
for x in words.readlines():
    liness.append(lines.rstrip('\n'))
```

When I print lines I get the list I want, but then when I use max() in the following way:

```
max(liness, key = len)
```

returns the `"a line from file.txt that containts \xe2 and \x80"` I know this probably has something to do with encoding, but I haven't had luck solving it. Anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce your error but used the following code:

```
words = open("directory/file.txt", 'r', 0)
line = words.readline()
wordlist = string.split(line)
```

Unfortunately, I was not able to reproduce your error as you would have guessed.  My file was txt file with a list of English words.

I assume that you are reading a .txt file with non-standard American English characters, correct?.  If you are not using American English characters, you might want to check out this post:

[Handling non-standard American English Characters and Symbols in a CSV, using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12357261/handling-non-standard-american-english-characters-and-symbols-in-a-csv-using-py)

You will need to determine what type of encoding/decoding to use based on your file.