# I want an **unicode type** of the following code ::

Tags: python, string, parsing, unicode

I got the below code from SO expert but it's working for ANSI Strings and my input is **UNICODE STRING**. How to make this code work for both of the versions? TIA

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict
summary = defaultdict(list)
csvin = csv.reader(open('qwetry.txt'), delimiter='|')
for row in csvin:
    summary[(row[1].split()[0], row[2])].append(int(row[5]))
csvout = csv.writer(open('datacopy.out','wb'), delimiter='|')
for who, what in summary.iteritems():
    csvout.writerow( [' '.join(who), len(what), sum(what)] )
```

courtsey: Jon Clements

Comment: Down voting should be accompanied with proper comments to make SO better.

Comment: Have a look at the chapter [Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/howto/unicode.html) in the python documentation.

Comment: Have a look @ this:: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/904041/reading-a-utf8-csv-file-with-python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **csv** module doesn’t directly support reading and writing Unicode. you can find the details [here](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html). The generator for the same is as below::

```
 import csv

def unicode_csv_reader(unicode_csv_data, dialect=csv.excel, **kwargs):
    # csv.py doesn't do Unicode; encode temporarily as UTF-8:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(utf_8_encoder(unicode_csv_data),
                            dialect=dialect, **kwargs)
    for row in csv_reader:
        # decode UTF-8 back to Unicode, cell by cell:
        yield [unicode(cell, 'utf-8') for cell in row]

def utf_8_encoder(unicode_csv_data):
    for line in unicode_csv_data:
        yield line.encode('utf-8')
```