# KeyError, related to ANSI vs UTF-8 Codec?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm new to python **and** programming, so I'm sure my code is the opposite of 'pythonic'.

My goal is to grab an excel file from a server, open it, write the data in the file to a new file.  Next I open that file and use dictReader to print a few columns from the file.  First I wrote a script to just open an excel file and print the columns.  I was able to achieve this.  Now I'm adding the next step of grabbing the file, writing it to a local file and then opening it.

I'm receiving the following error which I've researched a fair amount prior to posting:

```
  File "request.py", line 20, in <module>
    if line['Change'] == ticket_ID:
KeyError: 'Change'
```

Below is my code:

```
import csv
import sys
import urllib2

data = urllib2.urlopen("URL-HERE")

new_file = open("c:\\file-here", "w")
for fields in data:
    new_file.write(fields)
new_file.close()

test_file = 'getrequest6.csv'

csv_file = csv.DictReader(open(test_file, 'r'))

# ticket_ID = sys.argv[1]
ticket_ID = "RMSDB00010243"

for line in csv_file:
    if line['Change'] == ticket_ID:
        change_col = line['Change']
        review_col = line['Review']
        phase_col = line['Phase']
        print change_col, review_col, phase_col
```

What I've found is that the file I manually download from the server is of ANSI codec.  This file works when I open it.  The new file I create and write (getrequest6) is a UTF-8 codec.  I'm assuming that is the reason for the KeyError because when I copy and paste the data from the getrequest6 file, to the ANSI file, my code above works.

Any help would be appreciated.  I searched on the codecs class but I do not understand it.

Comment: No, the key `'Change'` will automatically be decoded to Unicode (using `'ASCII'` as the default encoding) as needed to compare against unicode values.

Comment: Do `print csv_file.next()` to get an idea of what keys *are* present in the file.

Comment: To save url to a local file, try: `import urllib; urllib.urlretrieve("URL_HERE", r"C:\file-here")`

Comment: interesting, when I do 'print csv_file.next()' it prints my third column first, then it prints the first column with this: "\xef\xbb\xbfChange", when the column name is "Change"?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian, thanks, I tried that, and it seems like a much better way than opening and writing the file!

Answer (score 1):

If the problem lies in the source csv files that some lines just lack 'Change', then what you can do (also a good practice in general) is to check the availability of that key in the dict:

```
# ...
if 'Change' in line and line['Change'] == ticket_id:
    # the rest
```

Comment: you could check it as: `if line.get('Change') == ticket_id:`. `.get()` returns `None` if there is no value for `'Change'` key.

Comment: when I do that it returns none.  So that means there is no value for the 'Change' key?

Comment: @RJP with `Change in line` you can check whether the key exists or not in line; with `line.get('Change') -> None`, you either have the possibility of key 'Change' does not exist and **default return** of `dict.get()` is None, or that the key does in fact exist and the value of that key is None (not likely, but possible from a pure Python perspective). Now to avoid this, you can do `line.get('Change', "KEY_NOT_EXIST")` which will return "KEY_NOT_EXIST" or anything you'd like to define if the key is not in the dict, to rule out one of the two possibilities aforementioned.

Comment: @woozyking: But you already know `None == ticket_id` is false, so there's no reason to treat non-existent and `None` as different in this case.

Comment: @woozyking I have the following:  `for line in csv_file:
 if line.get('Change', "KEY_NOT_EXIST") == ticket_ID:
  change_col = line['Change']
  review_col = line['Review']
  phase_col = line['Phase']
  print change_col, review_col, phase_col`

Comment: @woozyking, so I tried printing every other column in the excel file, and every Key works except for the "Change" one which is the first one?  I wonder why that is?

Comment: I think the problem is indeed related to BOM that @J.F.Sebastian mentioned. Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/904085/158111) or else a lazier way try line.get("\xef\xbb\xbfChange") or line.get(u"\xef\xbb\xbfChange") depends on the key type.

Answer (score 1):

> it prints the first column with this: "\xef\xbb\xbfChange", when the column name is "Change"

`b"\xef\xbb\xbf"` is [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) in utf-8.

The csv module doesn’t directly support reading and writing Unicode. But if you remove the BOM then it should be OK to use `csv` module with data encoded using utf-8:

```
import os
import shutil
from codecs import BOM_UTF8

with open(test_file, 'rb') as file, open(test_file+".utf8", 'wb') as outfile:
     chunk = file.read(len(BOM_UTF8))
     if chunk != BOM_UTF8: # don't write BOM
        outfile.write(chunk)
     shutil.copyfileobj(file, outfile)
os.remove(test_file)
os.rename(test_file+".utf8", test_file)
```

Comment: when I import shutil I get `AttributeError: module' object has no attribute 'copy2'`

Comment: @RJP: check that you don't have Python files in the current directory that have the same names as stdlib modules e.g., there should be no `copy.py`, `shutil.py` in cwd. Otherwise they are used instead of standard modules.

Comment: this worked, thanks a lot!  I'll read up on BOM as I've never heard of that