# List elements to variables

Tags: python

Inspired by the accepted answer to [Reading a UTF8 CSV file with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904041/reading-a-utf8-csv-file-with-python), I've tried the following but get

```
ValueError: need more than 5 values to unpack
```

Seems the empty strings are tripping me here. Is there a function I should apply to `row` to make this work? I'll need to work with these variables individually further down the line. Thanks.

```
 def encodevar(x):
     return x

 row = ['85123', '', '123 The Address', '', '', 'TUCSON', 'AZ ', 'The Company Name', '', '']
 for zip5,zip4,strname,strnumber,strsuite,city,state,busname,lname,fname in row:
            HHid = encodevar( zip5 )     +\
                   encodevar( zip4 )     +\
                   encodevar( stname )   +\
                   encodevar( stnumber ) +\
                   encodevar( stsuite )  +\
                   encodevar( busname )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looping *over* `row`, which means that each element is iterated over separately.

Just assign *directly* to your variables:

```
zip5, zip4, strname, strnumber, strsuite, city, state, busname, lname, fname = row
```

Because you were looping over the individual values, you were trying to unpack `zip5` value into your 10 names:

```
zip5, zip4, strname, strnumber, strsuite, city, state, busname, lname, fname = '85123'
```

Python then treats that string value, `'85123'` as a sequence of 5 characters, finding that those 5 don't fit into 10 names, throwing the exception you saw.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I'll check this answer when the 10mn wait is over.