# How to put a textfile into sqlite simply using Python API?

Tags: python, database, api, sqlite, csv

I have a tab delimited file in the format:

```
sentenceID (sid)    documentID (scid)   sentenceText (sent)
```

E.g.

```
100004  100 即便您喜爱流连酒吧，也定然在这轻松安闲的一隅，来一场甜蜜沉醉的约会。
100005  100 您可以慢慢探究菜单上所有的秘密惊喜。
```

I want to put it into sqlite3 with the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE sent (
    sid INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    scid INTEGER,
    sent TEXT,
    );
```

Is there a quick way to use the python API for sqlite (http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html) to put them into a table?

I've been doing it as such:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sqlite3 as lite
import sys, codecs

con = lite.connect('mycorpus.db')

with con:    
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Corpus(sid INT, scid INT, sent TEXT, PRIMARY KEY (sid))")
    for line in codecs.read('corpus.tab','r','utf8'):
        sid,scid,sent = line.strip().split("\t")
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO Corpus VALUES("+sid+","+scid+"'"+sent+"')")
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example using [unicodecsv](https://github.com/jdunck/python-unicodecsv) module:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import sqlite3

import unicodecsv


con = sqlite3.connect('mycorpus.db')
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Corpus(sid INT, scid INT, sent TEXT, PRIMARY KEY (sid))")

with open('corpus.tab', 'rb') as input_file:
    reader = unicodecsv.reader(input_file, delimiter="\t")
    data = [row for row in reader]

cur.executemany("INSERT INTO Corpus (sid, scid, sent) VALUES (?, ?, ?);", data)
con.commit()
```

Also see:

- [Reading a UTF8 CSV file with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904041/reading-a-utf8-csv-file-with-python)
- [Importing a CSV file into a sqlite3 database table using Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2887878/importing-a-csv-file-into-a-sqlite3-database-table-using-python)

Hope that helps.

Comment: quotes? I don't see quotes in your example. Anyway, you can pass appropriate `quotechar` to the reader object or set `quoting`. See [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.quotechar).

Comment: =) No worries your code works for input without `"` or `'`. Just that some of my other lines on the file has crazy quotation marks.

Answer (score 3):

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
    # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

    import sqlite3 as lite

    con = lite.connect('myCorpus.db')
    cur = con.cursor() 

    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE Corpus(sid INT, scid INT, sent TEXT, PRIMARY KEY (sid))")

    data=[row.split('\t') for row in file('myfile.tab','r').readlines()]
    cur.executemany("INSERT INTO Corpus (sid, scid,sent) VALUES (?, ?, ?);", data)

    con.commit()
```