# Python open CSV file with supposedly mixed encodings?

Tags: python, csv, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm trying read a CSV textfile (*UTF-8 without BOM according to Notepad++*) using Python. However there seems to be a problem with encoding:

```
print(open(path, encoding="utf-8").read())
```

> Codec can't decode byte **08xf**

This little character seems to be the problem: `●` (full string: "●• อีเปียขี้บ่น ت •●"), however I'm sure there will be more.

If I try UTF-16, then there is a message:

```
#also tried with encode
print(open(path, encoding="utf-16").read().encode('utf-8'))
```

> Illegal UTF-16 surrogate

Even when I try opening it with an automatic codec finder I receive the error.

```
def csv_unireader(f, encoding="utf-8"):
    for row in csv.reader(codecs.iterencode(codecs.iterdecode(f, encoding), "utf-8")):
        yield [e.decode("utf-8") for e in row]
```

**What am I overlooking? The file contains Twitter texts which contain a lot of different characters that's for sure. But this can't be such difficult task in Python, just reading/printing a file?**

**Edit:**

Just tried using the code from this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/14786752/45311

```
import csv

with open('source.csv', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

This at least prints some rows to the screen, but it also throws an error after some rows:

> **cp850.py**, line 19, in encode
>   return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0]
>   UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 62-63:
>   character maps to

It seems to automatically use `CP850` which is another encoding... I can't make sense out of all this....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is the version of your python?
If use the 2.x try to paste the import at the beginning of your script:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
```

than try:

```
print(open(path).read().encode('utf-8'))
```

There is also a great tool for charset detections: [chardet](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet).
I hope it'll help you.

Comment: `chardet` runs for ages on a 25mb file... Thanks for the lead though

Comment: The encoding is `ISO-8859-2` according to `chardet`

Comment: Did you try decode first, and than encode?  (.decode('iso-8859-2').encode('utf-8'))

Comment: Yes. I ended up copy/pasting the text in a new textfile. This was a workable solution for now.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the **errors** parameter in the open function. You can try one of the options below (I extracted the descriptions from python documentation):

- 'ignore' ignores errors. Note that ignoring encoding errors can lead to data loss.
- 'replace' causes a replacement marker (such as '?') to be inserted where there is malformed data.
- 'surrogateescape' will represent any incorrect bytes as code points in the Unicode Private Use Area ranging from U+DC80 to U+DCFF. These private code points will then be turned back into the same bytes when the surrogateescape error handler is used when writing data. This is useful for processing files in an unknown encoding.

So, you can use:

```
print(open(path, encoding="utf-8", errors="ignore").read())
```

Comment: I know it says to ignore errors, but I'm receiving the same error strangefully... "cp850.py, line 19, in encode return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_map)[0] UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 62-63: character maps to"

Comment: By the way, I tried to read a file with only this big dot character, and it worked well.

Comment: I think the last code in my post (after edit) throws an exception on a different character... (just doublechecked, and it's the same character) However according to `chardet` the encoding seems to be `ISO-8859-2`.

Comment: Maybe it's the character right after: `•` (smaller dot)