# Read csv with foreign language using pandas

Tags: python, csv, encoding, pandas, character-encoding

I am reading a csv  which has the following format
ID,Name,Description

Now some of my description contain foriegn langage characters like
[image],[image]

I would like to read this file into dataframe if possible. When I am using read_csv etcI am getting encoding errors. I tried

```
csv = pd.read_csv('foo.csv',encoding='utf-8')
```

but it throws encoding error

```
'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d
```

Is there any way to read the file keeping character set and keep analysing.
If not what would be the way to get such file into a dataframe or array like structure?

If keeping characters is not possible, then can such lines/words be ignored and read rest of the data? Help appreciated.

Comment: Is it literally like this `Mâ€lnda, Sâ€dertâ€žlje,`? If so, either your editor (where you are viewing the file) or the file itself is not encoded correctly.

Comment: Yea realized that. I was using editplus to view it. Now I have taken screenshot after opening it in excel as I did for eastern chars.

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/904041/reading-a-utf8-csv-file-with-python?rq=1

Comment: Are you sure its UTF-8? It seems like it isn't. You need to figure out what encoding is being used.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I am not sure and as its erroring out its not utf8. I am trying to understand how I can figure out the encoding.

Comment: Post raw input from your csv into the question (not as a comment) or a link to the file, if you're lucky the file will have a [BOM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark) which will indicate the encoding

Comment: @EdChum, will check that. Unfortunately, I wont be able to post the link of file as it is because some legal stuff. But I'll check if I can do something to make it postable