# Properly encoding sc.textFile data (python 2.7)

Tags: python, apache-spark, unicode, utf-8, ascii

My CSV was originally created by Excel. Anticipating encoding anomalies, I opened and re-saved the file with `UTF-8 BOM encoding` using Sublime Text.

**Imported into the notebook:**

```
filepath = "file:///Volumes/PASSPORT/Inserts/IMAGETRAC/csv/universe_wcsv.csv"
uverse = sc.textFile(filepath)
header = uverse.first()
data = uverse.filter(lambda x:x<>header)
```

**Formatted my fields:**

```
fields = header.replace(" ", "_").replace("/", "_").split(",")
```

**Structured the data:**

```
import csv
from StringIO import StringIO
from collections import namedtuple

Products = namedtuple("Products", fields, verbose=True)

def parse(row):
    reader = csv.reader(StringIO(row))
    row = reader.next()
    return Products(*row)

products = data.map(parse)
```

If I then do `products.first()`, I get the first record as expected. However, if I want to, say, see the `count by brand` and so run:

```
products.map(lambda x: x.brand).countByValue()
```

I still get an `UnicodeEncodeError` related `Py4JJavaError`:

```
File "<ipython-input-18-4cc0cb8c6fe7>", line 3, in parse
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xab' in    
position 125: ordinal not in range(128)
```

How can I fix this code?

Comment: You can check this question answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904041/reading-a-utf8-csv-file-with-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`csv` module in legacy Python versions doesn't support Unicode input. Personally I would recommend using Spark `csv` data source:

```
df = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv(filepath)
fields = [c.strip().replace(" ", "_").replace("/", "_") for c in df.columns]
df.toDF(*fields).rdd
```

For most applications `Row` objects should work as well as `namedtuple` (it extends `tuple` and provides similar attribute getters) but you can easily follow convert one into another.

You could also try reading data as without decoding:

```
uverse = sc.textFile(filepath, use_unicode=False)
```

and decoding fields manually after initial parsing:

```
(data
    .map(parse)
    .map(lambda prod: Products(*[x.decode("utf-8") for x in prod])))
```

Related question [Reading a UTF8 CSV file with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/904041/6910411)