# I want to read csv file using python27, but there is an error like" TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function"

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, encoding

here is my code:

```
import csv
file  = open('traintag1.csv','r',encoding='utf-8')
csv_reader = csv.reader(file)
for row in csv_reader:
    print row[-2]
```

then encounter an error like the title:

> file  = open('traintag1.csv','r',encoding='utf-8') TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function"

I wanna use 'encoding='utf-8' because when the file is full of Chinese, after reading file to print on screen the words are messy.
and when I add another line`from io import open` on the head, there again an error like this:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xbb in position 29: invalid start byte

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/904041/reading-a-utf8-csv-file-with-python

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `codecs` to open the file, this allows an encoding to be specified, for example:

```
import csv
import codecs

with codecs.open('traintag1.csv', 'rb', encoding="utf-8") as f_input:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(f_input)

    for row in csv_reader:
        print row[-2]
```

Comment: thank U, I am just so anoyed by the coding problem caused by python2.7