# Import values with special characters in a .csv file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have values in a .csv file that that look like this:

```
drieëntachtig
één
```

Now I try to read in the relevant values using the following commands;

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep=";")
numbers = df['numbers'].tolist()
```

However when I look at the values now I see this in my console:

```
drie�ntachtig
��n
```

Could anybody tell how I read the values in python 2.7 so I get the normal values? I already tried:

```
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', sep=";", encoding= "uft8")
```

Comment: You should write encoding, not encodeing. Does it work like that?

Comment: No, this was a typo...

Comment: It seems to me like this isn't an issue with Python, but the console you are outputting data too. Could you try opening a console/command prompt and enter `echo één`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading a UTF8 CSV file with Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/904041/reading-a-utf8-csv-file-with-python)

Comment: Are you sure that the encoding of the file is UTF8? The special characters shown here could be Latin1 or Latin9 or win1252... A simple option if to use an editor able to process different codepages like the excellents [gvim](http://www.vim.org) (multi-platform) or [notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/) (Windows)

Answer (score 1):

You could `encoding` it with `latin` when you read the csv file in pandas, refer to [standard-encodings](https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings):

```
df = pd.read_csv('character.csv', sep=";", encoding='latin')
```

Suppose you have content in `character.csv`:

```
test
drieëntachtig
één
banana
orange
apple
```

Then you print df, it will give you :

```
        test
0   drieëntachtig
1   één
2   banana
3   orange
4   apple
```