# Standard character encodings for pandas.read_csv

Tags: python, pandas, decode, encode

read_csv returns this error:
`Initializing from file failed` using `latin-1`, `utf-8 and` `ISO-8859-1`.

```
from pandas import *

df = dict(A=[1,2,3],B=['abc','efg','hig'],C=[100,200,300])
df = DataFrame(df)   
df

    A    B    C
0   1   abc  100
1   2   efg  200
2   3   hig  300
```

I wrote it with a German character as following:

```
df.to_csv('Lück.txt', sep='\t', encoding ='utf-8', index=False)
```

and it fails to import it in this way:

```
read_csv('Lück.txt', sep='\t', encoding = 'utf-8')
```

After all if there is ant method to detect special German character I would replace it.

P.S. I have seen number of posts in this issue, but none of them coincides with my question and I'm not good at standard character decode/encoding, thanks.

Comment: `Lück` is a variable?

Comment: Actually it is in a list of names, and the problem raises when variable arrives to  special german characters, but here to make an example I wrote it directly as string.

Comment: You can't concatenate a list with a string.

Comment: For export data there is no problem, `Lück.txt` is being created, the error raises when importing.

Comment: Did you make sure your script is written in utf-8 coding?

Comment: Yes, I just copied it here.

Comment: Omit the encoding... what happens?

Comment: Again, writes it correctly, gives me this error `'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe0 in position 4: unexpected end of data`

Comment: In that case, write with `latin-1` encoding and see if it works.

Comment: I have to do it in both writing and reading, is that true? By the way as I ha written above I proved also with that, same error `Initializing from file failed`.

Answer (score 1):

Chances are that the root cause is not the German umlaut, but one or more "weird" [whitespace](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/docs/9wpywmtd7ko/HjRTmdklBwAJ) characters within the .csv file. Those especially occur when the .csv file was modified by any kind of [copy/paste operation to excel](https://superuser.com/questions/466267/excel-destroying-special-character-when-saved-as-csv) beforehand.

First, begin your python script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python 
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*
```

Second, make sure that your .csv files do not contain any kind of weird whitespaace characters, as summarized [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14786752/6060083).

Comment: Thanks even though the problem isn't resolved. As you say it could be caused by read/write operations because originally this file has been created by the data extracted from `xlsx` file.