# csv file turkish characters not showing

Tags: python, django, encoding, utf-8

I am importing csv file to django model with below commands:

```
if request.method == 'POST' and request.FILES['csv_file2']:
    myfile = request.FILES['csv_file2']
    fs = FileSystemStorage()
    filename = fs.save(myfile.name, myfile)
    data = csv.reader(fs.open(filename, mode='r'))
```

The problem that I am having that I can't see turkish characters. I searched at stackoverflow  and I need to add utf-8 encoding while reading the csv file ,I tried several examples that I found but I couldn't make it work anywhere I tried to add encoding in my codes. Where should I add ?

Comment: I suppose you're using Python 2? If so, the `unicode_csv_reader` technique near the bottom of [this page](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) always helped me in those situations.

Comment: I am using python 3 actually

Comment: the example at python 3 like as follows : import csv
with open('some.csv', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)              While opening I need to add encoding='utf-8' but it's not working in my example   (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904041/reading-a-utf8-csv-file-with-python/904085#904085)

Comment: Yes, but that's with the built-in `open`, not `fs.open`, which apparently doesn't take an encoding parameter. You could try to get the path to the file and open it with built-in open, passing the encoding. I'm not used to working with `FileSystemStorage` directly, so I'm not sure about how it's usually done.

Comment: Yes, you can get the path with [`fs.path`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/files/storage/#django.core.files.storage.Storage.path).

Comment: I got different problems when I used directly built-in open because of that I had to switch fs.open  (The main problem was that built-in open couldn't reach the direct path of the file upload because it's dynamic but was working when it was static path.)

Comment: Hmm, Stack Overflow is suggesting to move this to chat, but I have to leave now. I don't know the specifics of why you need `fs.open`, but you could try calling `fs.path` immediately before the `open`, which presumably would get you the path that `fs.open` itself will use. Of course, it that path is not local it will fail, as the documentations warns.

Comment: I saw your link seems useful,I will try that if I can't find any solution with fs.open.Thank you Paulo

Comment: @İlkemÇetinkaya use https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html by setting the encoding in Python 2 if it's python 3, then that's the default.   https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html

Comment: why not use  built in python `open` https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/functions.html#open takes encoding as parameter.

Comment: Also are you sure your fs.save is saving with write encoding? you can simply use open to open for write.

Comment: I am not using fs.save because I only read the file and write to django database. I am now checking the links that you sent

Comment: instead of data = csv.reader(fs.open(filename, mode='r'))  I used   
   fs.path = filename
            data = csv.reader(open(fs.path))  but I am not getting Exception Type: FileNotFoundError

Comment: I also modified as like as follows path= os.readlink(filename)
            with open(path) as f:
                data= f.read()  still not able to read with built-in read method

Comment: @İlkemÇetinkaya The way to use `fs.path` would be: `path = fs.path(filename)` and then `csv.reader(open(path), encoding='utf8')`.

Comment: this is not working too :(  getting error at  data = csv.reader(open(path), encoding='utf-8')                          : Exception Type: TypeError Exception Value: 
'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo, the encoding is passed to `open` and not `csv.reader`. It's correct in ahmet's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to modify as per below:

```
            path = fs.path(filename)
            with open(path, encoding='utf-8') as f:
                data = csv.reader(f)
                for row in data:
```