# How to read whole line in pyspark with charset？

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm using pyspark to read textfiles which are encoded by gbk. So how can i use pyspark to read this files by gbk.

read.csv() can't read whole line, hadoopfile() only support 'utf-8'

Comment: You can go through this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904041/reading-a-utf8-csv-file-with-python

Comment: use pyspark,not only python