# How to fix "UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xca" error?

Tags: python, excel, csv, export-to-csv

I am trying to run an excel file with about 800 cells through my program. The program works for a file with about 15 cells perfectly. The error I am getting is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/first_lastname/Documents/CSVScraping.py", line 16, in <module>
    header = next(reader) #converts each row to a list
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xca in position 5214: invalid continuation byte
```

My code is the following:

```
import csv
from textblob import TextBlob
import string

z = 10
poscounter = 0
negcounter = 0
neucounter = 0
totalsentences = 0


outfile = open('/Users/first_lastname/Desktop/WebScraping/TripAdvisor/Juneau/analyzedData.csv', 'w')

with open('/Users/first_lastname/Desktop/WebScraping/TripAdvisor/Juneau/tripadvisor_2021.csv', 'r') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    header = next(reader) #converts each row to a list
    #[rows][columns]

    for row in reader:
        trip_review = row[2]
        #print(trip_review)
        y = trip_review.lower()
        y = y.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
        y1 = TextBlob(y)
        trip_sentiment = y1.sentiment.polarity
        xplitIt = y.split(" ")
        for something in xplitIt:
            if something == "crowded" or something == "busy" or something == "crowds" or something == "hate" or something == "hated":
                tripSentiment = -0.1
                break
            
        if trip_sentiment ==0:
            neucounter+=1
                
        elif trip_sentiment >0 and trip_sentiment <=1:
            poscounter+=1

        elif trip_sentiment == -0.1 or trip_sentiment < 0:
            negcounter+=1
            
        totalsentences = totalsentences + 1    
        line = "{};{}\n".format(trip_review, trip_sentiment)
        outfile.write(line)
outfile.close()

print(f"Positive Sentiment: {(poscounter/totalsentences) * 100} %")
print(f"Negative Sentiment: {(negcounter/totalsentences) * 100} %")
print(f"Neutral Sentiment: {(neucounter/totalsentences) * 100} %")
#print(totalsentences)
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this would be appreciated!!!!

Comment: I assume you should provide code page. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904041/reading-a-utf8-csv-file-with-python

Comment: What data is in the cell that generates the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Figured out that all I had to do was put in "encoding = latin-1" after r in the "with" function parameters