# Writing Python CSV files - encoding

Tags: python, csv, encoding, character-encoding

I open a .csv file and I write another .csv file in output.
I specified encoding='utf-8' for both files.
When I read the input file, in a dictionary, I have an accented character (ì) which I can see in the variables I use, but "ì" becomes "Ã¬" when I write it in the output file.

I create the output line by concatenating some variables, like this:
output_line = [name, address, citizenship_flag]

citizenship_flag may be "sì" or "no".
In the output file it becomes "Ã¬".

Where am I wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/904041/reading-a-utf8-csv-file-with-python) discussion can help.

Comment: The file is correctly written as UTF-8.  `'Ã¬'` is `'ì'` written as UTF-8 but read as (probably) Windows-1252 encoding instead.  It is the program reading your output file that is the problem (Excel?).  Many Windows programs require UTF-8 w/ BOM to read UTF-8 correctly or assume the ANSI encoding, which varies by localized version of Windows.  US Windows uses Windows-1252.  Use `encoding='utf-8-sig'` to generate the output with a BOM marker that apps like Excel use to recognize and decode UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize that it was Excel's fault when opening the file.

Comment: Try opening a blank Excel worksheet, click Data > From Text/CSV...  follow the wizard and select the correct encoding